# Where do you live?

Tags: discussion, community

With an eye toward designing in-person community events (e.g. [this](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-we-plan-a-shabbaton-mi-yodeya)), it would be useful to have some idea of how many Yodeyans live where.

So, let's try to collect some basic data about this while preserving the privacy of people who want it preserved.

**If you see the metropolitan area you live in as an answer, please vote it up.**

<sup>To search among the answers for (e.g.) `London`, type

`is:answer inquestion:this London`

in the search box at the top-right corner of this page and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Note, though, that that effort will be stymied if you search for `Golders Green` and the answer here says `Hendon`.

In the United States, it may be most productive to search using the two-letter postal abbreviation for your (or a neighboring) state.</sup>

**If you do not see it as an answer, either:**

- Please post a comment on this question asking for your city to be added, then vote it up when it's added, or
- If you want to keep your location private, please flag this question for mod attention with a note saying which community you want added, then vote it up when it's added.

Please don't add your own city yourself, since then, you won't be able to vote it up.

Please don't vote any of the answers down.

If you are relatively nomadic, please upvote where you'll be for the next bit, and feel free to flag for a mod to edit and free up your vote when necessary.

Comment: Should we post as an option: on the server farm?

Comment: It can take three hours to get from Far Rockaway to Washington Heights by public transport. That's fine for a shabbaton, not so much for a lunch meeting. Perhaps we should split up the NYC answer? Or maybe leave it as is, with further splitting being done by the New Yorkers as needed later?

Comment: @msh210, so far we have one user who's owned up to being from NY. We could break it down beyond metro areas later, when we have many per metro area.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, makes sense.

Comment: It occurred to me that some people might regularly enough be in two of these places (eg. tel aviv and yerushalyim, various of the NYC area places, or even someone who communtes between two cities). Should they mark twice if they are possibly interested in either locale?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think yes, if the two locations are not adjacent (e.g. your first two examples). That way, we'll know about multiple locations when they're truly multiple. What do you think?

Answer (score 13):

[New York City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City) (NY)

Comment: related [Monsey, NY](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1658/759)

Comment: related [Teaneck, NJ / Elizabeth, NJ / North Jersey](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1656/759)

Comment: related [Lakewood, NJ](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1657/759)

Answer (score 8):

[Jerusalem, Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem)

Comment: related: [Beit Shemesh, Israel](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4082)

Answer (score 8):

[Washington, DC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.)

Comment: related [Baltimore, MD](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1654/759)

Answer (score 6):

[Teaneck, NJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaneck) / [Elizabeth, NJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth,_New_Jersey) / [North Jersey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Jersey)

Comment: related [New York City (NY)](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1636/759)

Comment: related [Monsey, NY](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1658)

Answer (score 5):

[Tel Aviv / Gush Dan, Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gush_Dan)

Answer (score 5):

[Toronto, ON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto)

Answer (score 5):

[Baltimore, MD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baltimore)

Comment: related [Washington, DC](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1640/759)

Answer (score 4):

[Haifa, Israel / Northern Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haifa)

Answer (score 4):

[Pittsburgh, PA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pittsburgh)

Answer (score 4):

[Lakewood, NJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakewood,_New_Jersey)

Comment: related [New York City (NY)](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1636/759)

Comment: related [Deal, NJ / Jersey Shore](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1680/759)

Answer (score 3):

[Los Angeles, CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles)

Answer (score 3):

[Beit Shemesh,  Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beit_Shemesh)

Comment: related: [Jerusalem, Israel](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1638)

Answer (score 3):

[Modi'in-Maccabim-Re'ut, Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modi%27in-Maccabim-Re%27ut) and environs

Comment: Coolio. Looks like I have neighbor-members.

Answer (score 2):

[Philadelphia, PA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philadelphia)

Answer (score 2):

[Melbourne, Victoria, Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melbourne)

Answer (score 2):

[Costa Rica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Costa_rica)

Answer (score 2):

[Atlanta, GA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlanta)

Answer (score 2):

[Minneapolis - St. Paul, MN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minneapolis_%E2%80%93_Saint_Paul)

Answer (score 2):

[Miami area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_metropolitan_area) / [South FL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Florida)

Answer (score 2):

[Beirut, Lebanon](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beirut)

Answer (score 1):

[San Diego, CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Diego,_California)

Answer (score 1):

[Manchester, UK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester)

Answer (score 1):

[Sydney, NSW, Australia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_Sydney)

Answer (score 1):

[Houston, TX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Houston)

Answer (score 1):

[Johannesburg, South Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannesburg)

Answer (score 1):

[Boston, MA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston)

Answer (score 1):

[Phoenix, AZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix,_Arizona)

Answer (score 1):

[San Francisco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco) / [Oakland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oakland,_California) / [Bay Area, CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_Area)

Answer (score 1):

[Nairobi, Kenya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nairobi,_Kenya) or anywhere in Africa outside of [South Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Africa)

Comment: cf. [Johannesburg, South Africa](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1662)

Comment: Perhaps we should restrict this to Subsaharan Africa.

Comment: @msh210 How would you notify the voter?

Comment: IIRC this answer was posted in response to someone's request, in which case that person is almost certainly the voter, and that person had indicated a location of Nairobi.

Comment: @msh210 The request was made by me in honor of Vram (or whatever his name is now). I have no idea when it was upvoted or by whom.

Answer (score 1):

[Cleveland, OH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleveland,_Oh)

Comment: related [Columbus, OH](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1671/759)

Answer (score 1):

[Beer Sheva, Israel / Southern Israel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_Sheva,_Israel)

Answer (score 1):

[São Paulo, Brazil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sao_Paulo,_Brazil)

Answer (score 1):

[Tarapoto, Peru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarapoto)

Answer (score 1):

[Longmeadow, Massachusetts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longmeadow,_Massachusetts).

Answer (score 0):

[Chicago, IL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago)

Answer (score 0):

[London, England](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London)

Answer (score 0):

[Omaha, NE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omaha)

Answer (score 0):

[St. Louis, MO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Louis)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: related [Kansas City, KS / MO](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1679/759)

Answer (score 0):

[Montreal, QC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec)

Answer (score 0):

[Monsey, NY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monsey,_ny)

Comment: related [New York City (NY)](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1636/759)

Comment: related [Teaneck, NJ / Elizabeth, NJ / North Jersey](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1656)

Answer (score 0):

[Memphis, TN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memphis,_Tennessee)

Answer (score 0):

[Birmingham, AL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birmingham,_Alabama)

Answer (score 0):

[Detroit, MI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_Detroit)

Answer (score 0):

[Columbus, OH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbus,_Oh)

Comment: related [Cleveland, OH](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1672/759)

Answer (score 0):

[Western Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Canada)

Answer (score 0):

[Seattle, WA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle) and its vicinity

Answer (score 0):

[Paris, France](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris)

Answer (score 0):

[Germany](http://enwp.org/Germany)

Answer (score 0):

[Kansas City, KS / MO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kansas_City_metropolitan_area)

Comment: related [St. Louis, MO](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1651/759)

Answer (score 0):

[Deal, NJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal,_New_Jersey) / [Jersey Shore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey_Shore)

Comment: related [Lakewood, NJ](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1657/759)

Comment: Should all of the NJ-NYC posts be combined?

Answer (score 0):

[Dallas, TX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dallas,_Texas)

Answer (score 0):

[Midland, TX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland,_Texas)

Answer (score 0):

[Denver, CO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denver,_Colorado)