# Can you help distribute "Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?"

Tags: discussion, days-of-awe-project

You may have heard that we're [working on another book for the high holy days](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3591/472).  This time, in addition to the downloadable copy, we're talking about printing and distributing copies in places where they'll be welcome and useful.

As Isaac said in the proposal:

> They are the holidays on which the most Jews spend the most time in synagogues. A machzor companion could be distributed physically very effectively in synagogues, and could be useful for synagogue-attendees as reading material that supplements and enhances their synagogue experience.

You used the haggadah at your seder and may have sent people home with copies.  You used the Purim book in your *mishloach manot* bags.  You used the Chanukah book at candle-lighting each night.  (Ok, maybe not you personally, but some of you did each of these things.)  And now, you might share the upcoming publication in your synagogue, kollel, or yeshiva.

**Will you help us with distribution?**  We're not asking you to pay for the copies you'll use; we're just asking who would be willing to receive a box of books and do a little leg-work to put stacks of them in suitable places.  If you would *also* like to help defray costs, please visit [our funding page](http://jewcer.com/miyodeya).

According to [this survey](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1635/472) we have Yodeyans in New York, New Jersey, Toronto, Baltimore, and many other cities not yet covered by volunteers.  Can you help?

**If you would like to distribute copies of *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* at your local congregation, please fill out [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rYOcvW2ZGyXHaZMgUzcxuqJ_YqTMx-Xm-BE1BKtw0CY/viewform) <s>by Tuesday, August 11th.</s> We will continue to accept requests while supplies last.**  Personal information entered here will only be viewed by Mi Yodeya moderators and by members of the project team (currently only Isaac Moses, who is arranging the mailings) who need it for mailing purposes.

If it would be helpful, in getting permission to distribute *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* in your congregation, to show the actual book to a decision-maker, you can provide them with [this review draft](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0TqzcduQYHTWW9JVXJpSzdoUDg/view?usp=sharing). It is 99% the same as the final version will be, pending things like proofreading and final updates to the Credits. Please note that while this draft contains a few instances of [non-erasable Holy Names](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/43668/2), this will be corrected before we finalize and publish.

Soon after August 11th, when we have determined how many copies to print and put in the order, we'll be in touch about when to expect your shipment and how many copies to expect.

Answer (score 4):

**Thanks very much to those who responded, below. Whether you previously responded or not, please enter your finalized request on [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rYOcvW2ZGyXHaZMgUzcxuqJ_YqTMx-Xm-BE1BKtw0CY/viewform) by Tuesday, August 11th.**

If you have already provided some of this information, we apologize for the duplication. This form will ensure that we have all of the information we need to get the print copies where they need to go.

---

<s>Please edit this entry (or, email the moderators at mi.yodeya@gmail.com) if you can help with distribution.  Please give us:</s>

- your username
- where you can distribute copies (city)
- how many copies you think you could use

---

- Monica Cellio, Pittsburgh PA, 50-100 *(I have requests pending.)*
- Scimonster, *somewhere in Israel*, 20
- Noach mi Frankfurt, Boston Area, MA, 100+
- msh210, St. Louis, Mo., at least 35  *(I have a request out to another synagogue and am waiting on a reply.)*
- Daniel, Atlanta, GA., Like msh210 An unknown amount.
- Anonymous, Manhattan ("[near JTS](//goo.gl/maps/8ScEu)"), requests pending.
- Anonymous, Philadelphia (2 people/shuls), requests pending.
- Anonymous, Manhattan (Washington Heights and Upper East Side), 36-50 (pending further consideration)
- izmargad, Oceanside, NY (50-100)
- Ze'ev Felsen, Potomac, MD, unknown number
- Anonymous, Dallas, TX, number TBD
- DanF, 2 shuls in South Shore Long Island, 200 copies for both shuls.

Comment: Does anyone have a sense of how many booklets we can actually print? We may have more demand here than supply.

Comment: @doubleAA we're talking about costs & distribution in the chat room. Further donations will help us print more; if we have more demands than funding we may have to send everybody fewer than requested. We'll do our best!

Comment: @izmargad please note the update regarding filling in [a form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rYOcvW2ZGyXHaZMgUzcxuqJ_YqTMx-Xm-BE1BKtw0CY/viewform) with your finalized request by August 11th. Thanks!

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen please note the update regarding filling in [a form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rYOcvW2ZGyXHaZMgUzcxuqJ_YqTMx-Xm-BE1BKtw0CY/viewform) with your finalized request by August 11th. Thanks!

Comment: @IsaacMoses, still waiting to hear from folks, so I haven't filled it out yet.