# "And Revision, and Houses of Prayer, And Tzedaka Distribute the Goodness of Mi Yodeya!" (Please help.)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, days-of-awe-project

You may have noticed by now that Mi Yodeya has been working on our fourth [publication](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications) - ימים נוראים - מי יודע?‏ / *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*. This is our most ambitious publication project yet, since we're combining the size of our first and largest publication, *Hagada - Mi Yodeya?* with the reader-accessibility and quality-control measures we've developed in *Purim - Mi Yodeya?* and *Chanukah - Mi Yodeya?*, and then, for the first time, doing an actual, physical, ink-on-paper print run, and distributing free copies to congregations all over the place.

[image: Sample booklet posed with Days of Awe objects]

We have completed the first couple of stages of the project, collecting and doing initial edits on relevant Mi Yodeya content, and we are at a stage in which, for the next week especially, every pair of Yodeyan hands we can get will bring the project closer to successful completion. Here are three ways in which you can make your own contribution - small or large - over the coming week:

- [**Revision**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/help-edit-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya)
  We have produced the first complete draft of *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*, and are now going through multiple rounds of copyediting, proofreading, and revisions. You can jump in and help by visiting the [project chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25414/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya), downloading the most recent draft (linked in the top-right, under the room title), and posting messages with corrections and critiques. Don't worry about duplicating others' efforts; the more eyes, the better.
- [**Houses of Prayer**](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/can-you-help-distribute-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya)
  Would people in your congregation like to be able to pick up a free copy of *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* when they go to shul for Rosh Hashana or Yom Kippur? Yes, at least some of them would. If you would like to help Mi Yodeya to spread its content to the world and your co-congregants to have something edifying and intriguing to read over the holidays, [sign up](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3597/can-you-help-distribute-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) <s>**By Tuesday, August 11th**</s> (We are still accepting requests while supplies last.) to receive a box of copies in the mail and then put them out where people can get them.
- [**Tzedaka**](http://jewcer.com/project/help-publish-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya)
  It is expensive to print up lots of copies of a booklet. We've estimated that it is going to cost about $3 per booklet to print and ship *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?*. We are doing all of the other labor ourselves, as a community of volunteers, but we need to pay the printer and the postman. Fortunately, we have a special, [generous offer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/how-shall-we-fund-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) on the table to double-match up to the first $500 we can raise toward this project, meaning that if we can raise that much, we can give out about 500 booklets. So, we've set up a [crowd-funding project](http://jewcer.com/project/help-publish-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) to raise at least that much. Within about two weeks, enough donors came forward to max out the match, so we expect to be able to print at least 500 copies. The only question is how many more. Can you [spare](http://jewcer.com/project/help-publish-days-of-awe-mi-yodeya) $5 or more to help make *Days of Awe - Mi Yodeya?* available to even more interested readers?

If you have any questions about any aspect of this project, you can post them as responses to this post, or drop by the project's [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25414/days-of-awe-mi-yodeya).

Help in one, two, or three ways, a little or a lot. Contribute a little bit of your time, your place, or your resources, and you'll have taken your part in this exciting project. Thank you!