# Shabbaton - Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion

Inspired by [*How can we plan a "Shabbaton - Mi Yodeya?"*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/how-can-we-plan-a-shabbaton-mi-yodeya)

Assuming that the above is properly considered, I for one think it would be lovely if we could perhaps start to plan an annual shabbaton for Mi Yodeya members.

I have posted this to reignite discussion.

Comment: +1. So this is part of "Step 1" from the [answer there](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1627/5323)? ;-)

Comment: @IsaacMoses I disagree. See my above comment

Comment: @Shokhet, so far, this post is basically a "+1" for that one, which is valuable and welcome, but not really a new question/proposal. If this post is edited to offer substantive/distinct question or proposal, I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I see what you're saying. That's fair.

Comment: Regarding "reignite discussion", see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers. (The stuff it mentions about bounty, though, doesn't apply on Meta.)