# Tenth Birthday Project: Topics

Tags: discussion, 10th-birthday-project

Is it a bit early for this? Maybe. We'll see.

[Previously on MY.Meta:](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4898/)

> How about a commemorative publication? "Mi Yodeya - the first ten years" or something like that. Our other publications are themed; this one, in contrast, would be a collection of interesting and/or important questions and answers on a broader range of topics. Such a volume could be particularly good to give away to friends and colleagues as an introduction to the site.

In the spirit of making a collection of "interesting and/or important questions and answers on a broader range of topics," this thread is intended to compile a master list of the topics covered in such a publication.

I've made a community wiki answer to collect such a list. If you think it's "interesting and/or important" enough to include, add the tag to the list; if you're not sure, feel free to leave a comment with the proposal.

- This list is by no means final and will be pruned down in later drafts. We're dealing with ten years' worth of content on literally anything to do with Judaism, so expect the list to be long. Better that it be too long and we cut it down, than it be too short and we not have anything to work with.
- It seems that people want to jump right to collecting questions, rather than focusing on tags. In that case, go ahead and add questions to the answer box below.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I disagree with your upvoting everything because that’s not what upvotes are for. On the main site, it’s to designate posts which are useful, and on here, it’s posts which you agree with or think are good ideas. Handing out upvotes for no reason whatsoever is not what they’re for.

Comment: What should we do about PTIJ? Certainly that's an integral part of MY culture that should be included. Should we look for the funniest PTIJ?

Comment: Yes- that’s just my personal purim policy

Answer (score 1):

## Add your questions here!

- [Implications of Samoa skipping a Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday)
- [Why is it necessary to ask a Rabbi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)
- [Did any Achronim comment on the American Revolutionary or Civil Wars?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/did-any-achronim-comment-on-the-american-revolutionary-or-civil-wars)
- [How do we know that God exists?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-do-we-know-that-god-exists)
- [About what were rabbis ahead of the times?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22851/about-what-were-rabbis-ahead-of-the-times)
- [mi-yodeya-series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series)
- [Is Christianity Avodah Zara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-christianity-avodah-zara)
- [Does the Torah discuss aliens?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens)
- [How do I get myself to yearn for moshiach if I'm comfortable in the diaspora?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26908/how-do-i-get-myself-to-yearn-for-moshiach-if-im-comfortable-in-the-diaspora)
- [How to tactfully circumvent opposite-gender handshake](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/how-to-tactfully-circumvent-opposite-gender-handshake)

Comment: Some of these questions are popular enough to have highly upvoted bad answers. What do we do about those?

Comment: @DoubleAA If it has other, better answers, we can always leave out the bad ones. What questions did you have in mind that would be an issue, in that including them absolutely necessitates including bad answers?