# 10th Birthday Publication

Tags: discussion, celebration, 10th-birthday-project

As I [mentioned earlier](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4907/16354), I think it would be a nice idea to have more of a polished publication in honor of MY's 10th birthday. If all goes as planned, we could have an edited PDF booklet that could be distributed online, or even in print to places which might respect the site more if they see what type of information we have to share.

Please sign up by answering below if you can volunteer to help with any part of this project.  An answer to this question would include your username, and what you could contribute.  Please try to be as specific as possible.

For example, you could:

- link to a post of your own and offer to rewrite it as a Hebrew article
- link to a post of your own and offer to rewrite it as an English article
- offer to help typeset the publication
- offer to help edit the publication
- offer to brainstorm sections and general layout
- offer to work on online dissemination
- offer to spearhead distribution in your area
- or anything else

Some of those suggestions are still pretty broad, but I want to get a good idea of what we might be able to accomplish.

Looking forward to working with you!

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5023/

Answer (score 4):

I would be happy to help edit, assuming processes similar to our past publications.  I'm a pretty good copy-editor for English, and you should definitely ask somebody else to review/proofread/edit Hebrew.  (Even for text I can understand, my Hebrew spelling is terrible.)

Answer (score 2):

I would be happy to develop [Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146/472) into an English article (integrating content from several answers).

I think this would be a useful accompaniment to a publication from an Internet community that tackles a lot of *halacha* questions.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't volunteering (yet) but a suggestion for this publication that I want feedback on:

I think it'd be great to have a chapter with highlights from our [mishna project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/472) -- an introduction about what we did and a sampling of interesting questions and answers that arose (or were revisited) from it.

Comment: By "kuntres" (which I only noticed in your question after writing this) it looks like you mean something like a scholarly journal, so maybe this doesn't fit with that and should be a separate publication tied to that project.  I don't know the word "kuntres" except from your meta posts, so I can't tell if this fits.

Comment: קונטרס ~ booklet

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks.  The answer linked from this meta question, which I only looked at after answering here, sounds like something more formal, so I hope רבות will clarify.

Comment: To me, the more formal the better, but it will depend on what the MY community moves toward...

Answer (score 1):

I would be happy to develop https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99340/16354 into a written Hebrew piece and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94370/16354 into an English article.

Answer (score -3):

I have offered my downvote on this project. If the idea is to be taken serious among the serious Torah world (unsure myself what that means), I do not wish for serious authority (of really any kind, if that is the implication) to be given to the  anonymity of the internet and its users.

Regardless of my personal opinion in regards to the public, I can offer my hand in assistance; I am interested to have a go. Specifically, I would be able to translate into Hebrew. Exactly what, would be up to others, most likely. Also, I may offer my opinion concerning what the Hebrew language would entail in this context. I reckon the articles written in Hebrew be made up excluding all modern language. For example, it would be an article that Rashi or Rambam will understand. Furthermore, between these two styles mentioned of Rashi and Rambam, perhaps Rambam’s would be more suitable, because of his non-usage of Aramaic unlike Rashi.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I'm not sure what you mean by serious authority given to the internet - we are not looking to offer psak (or show that we can offer psak), but more so that we can learn and share useful information... And thanks for the offer to help edit; I too would stay away from Modern Hebrew.

Comment: Ah yes, but the point is that it is anonymous and therefore cannot be compared to what is not anonymous. Otherwise, seems swell

Comment: why not? I can read a parsha article authored by whomever and compare it to another article. I'm not quite sure I understand you. (BTW, I didn't downvote, I think your post makes a good offer, even if I disagree with your opening statement.)

Comment: I disagree with most of what you said. Modern Hebrew is much clearer and will reach a larger audience. When Rashi and Rambam come back to life they (and the Satmers!) will be quickly learning Modern Hebrew anyway to integrate into the larger Jewish society. Besides, maybe we should type them all in strictly biblical Hebrew so Yehoshua and David would understand?

Comment: @DoubleAA The point of not using Modern Hebrew is so that the publication is available to Torah Learning Jews as a whole. They will understand the language because of their background in Torah learning, which is our audience, correct? Also, those were only examples, but equally as good would be חתם סופר or גר״א. And yes indeed Biblical Hebrew is automaticity included in all further iterations of the language (including modern Hebrew!), but obviously we would not limit ourselves to it.

Comment: No, that's not accurate. Many Jews don't understand words Rashi would have used comfortably. If you want the largest audience than exclude anything from Modern Hebrew as well as any Aramaic and Yiddishisms.

Comment: @DoubleAA that’s what I was implying by ‘Rambam’

Comment: Even Rambam isn't fully accessable to a modern Hebrew speaker. You may have grown up speaking Yeshivish but many Jews haven't and have to train to read rabbinic texts.

Comment: @Dr. Shmuel why write in Hebrew at all then? English is probably understood by more viewers than (semi) ancient Hebrew.