# To celebrate Mi Yodeya's 10th birthday, let's divide and conquer the entire Mishna, Mi-Yodeya-style!

Tags: discussion, celebration, group-siyum

[image: Hebrew word "Mishnayot" in fancy old text]

### Ten years of Mi Yodeya -- let's learn some Mishna!

Mi Yodeya [will be celebrating](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/how-shall-we-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday) our tenth birthday in Kislev 5780 / December 2019! As ten is traditionally the Mishna birthday<sup>1</sup>, let's mark this auspicious occasion by completing a collective study of the entire corpus of [Mishna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah).<sup>2</sup> Everyone who's ever used Mi Yodeya is invited to take part by studying one or more of the Mishna's 523 chapters. We'll finish with a completion party ([siyum](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siyum)) or parties on a date to be determined in Kislev/December.

#### Here's what to do:

1. **Choose a tractate.** The 63 tractates of Mishna, organized into their six orders, are listed in the [accepted answer below](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5104/2), along with the number of chapters and mishnayot (~paragraphs) in each one.<sup>3</sup> Pick a tractate, and click on it to go to its sign-up post.<sup>4</sup>
2. **Claim a chapter.** On the sign-up post, select *one chapter* that's not already claimed. (You can pick another when you finish this one!) Claim it by adding your name<sup>5</sup> after "Claimed by:".

   > - O Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: *your name here*

   If you'd like to dedicate your learning to a loved one's memory, you can add that information after your name.
3. **Learn that chapter!** At a minimum, read and understand the text of the Mishna. As the Mishna's language and structure can be cryptic, we recommend using at least one commentary or elucidating translation, or studying the associated chapter in the Talmud. [Here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101242/what-should-i-use-for-mishna-study)'s a list of in-print and electronic resources (some of them free online) you can use. Go as broad and as deep as you like!

   As you're learning, take note of questions that come up in your mind, even if you immediately find answers for them, to be ready for ...
4. **The Mi Yodeya twist:** Find a Mi Yodeya question or answer (or a few, if you can) that relates directly to your chapter, or post a question or answer that came up in your learning. Add a link to that post below where you signed up.

   > - O Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: *your name here*
   >     http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/######/your-question-about-chapter-3

   If you find a chapter that someone has kindly already added a link to, you may skip to Step 5, but do feel free to add more links.

   If you come across a question or answer that relates to any particular chapter of Mishna (or Talmud), even one you're not learning, consider kindly adding a link here!
5. **Mark it complete.** When you've completed your study of your chapter and added a Mi Yodeya link for it, change the 'O' at the beginning of the sign-up line to an 'X'.

   > - X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: *your name here*
   >     http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/######/your-question-about-chapter-3
6. **Repeat** steps 1-6.
7. If you can, **add the relevant tag and a short summary of the tractate** (if not already done).  Don't worry if you can't write a complete summary; some information is better than none, and the community is invited to edit further.

The minimum time investment per chapter is probably an hour or two. Try one! We really want to get as many people as we can involved. If you would like a study partner to help you out, leave a comment here or drop by [our chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam), and we'll find you one.

[Click here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5107/siyum-project-progress-and-how-to-help) to see how far we've gotten so far. At the end of this, God-willing, we'll not only have worked together to complete a study of the entire Mishna, we'll have something to show for our efforts: an index of Q&A covering all 523 chapters of the Mishna. Let's make it happen!

---

<sup>1. According to the program set forth by R' Yehuda ben Teima in [Avot 5:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.21?lang=bi).</sup>
<sup>2. Thanks to [DonielF](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4899/2) , [Daniel](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4900/2), and [Double AA](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/how-shall-we-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday#comment15354_4900) for brainstorming concepts for this intiative.</sup>
<sup>3. Lists generated using [Double AA's spreadsheet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18896/2) as a base. Synopses adapted from [Wikipedia's "Mishnah" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishnah#Structure).</sup>
<sup>4. If you prefer, you can scroll through all of sign-up posts in order by [sorting this post's answers by oldest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/rfc-to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entir?answertab=oldest#tab-top).</sup>
<sup>5. If you're new to Mi Yodeya and don't yet have the ability to edit the lists here, email us at mi.yodeya@gmail.com, and we'll help you out.</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91633/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-moses-to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday-l).

Comment: Do we need/want a rule to prevent the same question being used for more than one chapter. For instance [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33770/the-abolition-of-vidui-maaser) currently appears under Ma'aser Sheni 5, but could equally well be listed under Sotah 9.

Comment: @joel it's clearly more related to the rest of the chapter in Maaser Sheni which is why I put it there

Comment: Glad to see this is happening! Can we claim chapters that we're learning anyway (e.g. as part of another mishna project)?

Comment: @Daniel That's an interesting question about such projects in general. It may be worth posing to a rabbi, both at an individual level and at a community level.

Comment: (Re the above comments, fwiw, I'm claiming chapters I'm learning anyway as part of another project.) I see people who are signed up for >1 non-completed chapter at a time. Am I misunderstanding the rules that that's a no-no?

Comment: @msh210 claiming more than one chapter at a time is contrary to the instructions; in the one case of it I've noticed, the claimant had completed all the learning already and, I guess, hasn't yet had a chance to find/write related posts. Not the end of the world.

Comment: This will set a hard precedent to follow when Mi Yodeya turns 15.

Comment: @Y  e  z Not so hard if we start five years ahead instead of eight months! :)

Comment: Are we allowed to claim multiple chapters with the intent of learning them Shavuos night?

Comment: @DonielF That's not really consistent with the way this is set up, but I don't think anyone would be too offended. Bear in mind that the risk of two people learning the same multiple chapters over the holiday isn't that great, and the "cost," if it comes to pass, isn't that great either.

Comment: @IsaacMoses what if someone claimed a chapter in March or May and hasn't updated that he learned them. Could I learn this one chapter as well (as part of learning the tractate), mark it as learned and leave their name there? Credit matters less than completion I would say but you decide

Comment: @mbloch I would recommend at least trying to make contact first to see what their intentions are.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thanks, I will try, not sure I can ping them through the meta entry, but will leave another comment on one of their questions

Comment: @IsaacMoses So I did not get answers to my requests (I pinged both on meta and on their latest answer) whether they were still committed to learn these chapters. FYI their original commitments date from March and May. In the meantime, I learned both Masechet Rosh Hashana and Megilla. I let you decide if you prefer to wait for the original two to learn their chapters - or prefer to declare victory now and call these two *masechtot* complete. From my perspective there is no need to change the user attribution unless you prefer to do so.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118924/170

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Six Orders of the Mishna, and their 63 Tractates

Following each tractate name is either "(#/##)" for the number of chapters and mishnayot in the tractate or "(✓)" indicating that we've completed study of that tractate.

- #### Zeraim (Seeds)

  Prayer and blessings, tithes, and agricultural laws

  [Berachot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5030) (✓),   [Peah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5031) (8/69),  [Demai](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5032) (✓),    [Kilayim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5033) (9/77),   [Sheviit](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5034) (10/89),  [Terumot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5035) (✓),  [Maasrot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5036) (✓),  [Maaser Sheni](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5037) (✓),     [Challah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5038) (✓),  [Orlah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5039) (3/35),     [Bikurim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5040) (✓)
- #### Moed (Festival)

  The laws of the Sabbath and the Festivals

  [Shabbat](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5041) (✓),   [Eruvin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5042) (10/96),   [Pesachim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043) (✓),     [Shekalim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5044) (8/52),  [Yoma](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5045) (✓),     [Sukkah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5046) (✓),   [Beitzah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5047) (✓),  [Rosh HaShanah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5048) (✓),    [Taanit](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5049) (✓),   [Megilah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5050) (✓),  [Moed Katan](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5051) (✓),    [Chagigah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5052) (✓)
- #### Nashim (Wives)

  Marriage and divorce, some forms of oaths, and the laws of the nazirite

  [Yevamot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5053) (✓),    [Ketubot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5054) (13/111),     [Nedarim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5055) (✓),  [Nazir](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5056) (✓),    [Sotah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057) (✓),    [Gittin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5058) (✓),   [Kidushin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5059) (✓)
- #### Nezikin (Damages)

  Civil and criminal law, the functioning of the courts, and oaths

  [Bava Kamma](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5060) (✓),     [Bava Metzia](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5061) (✓),  [Bava Batra](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5062) (✓),   [Sanhedrin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5063) (✓),    [Makkot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5064) (✓),   [Shevuot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5065) (✓),   [Eduyot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5066) (✓),   [Avoda Zara](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5067) (✓),   [Avot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5068) (✓),     [Horayot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5069) (✓)
- #### Kodshim (Holy things)

  Sacrificial rites, the Temple, and the dietary laws

  [Zevachim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5070) (✓),   [Menachot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5071) (✓),     [Chullin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5073) (✓),  [Bechorot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5074) (✓),  [Arachin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5075) (✓),   [Temurah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5076) (✓),   [Kereitot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5077) (6/43),  [Meilah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5078) (✓),    [Tamid](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5079) (✓),    [Middot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5080) (✓),   [Kinnim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5081) (✓)
- #### Taharot (Purities)

  The laws of purity and impurity, including the impurity of the dead, the laws of food purity, and bodily purity

  [Kelim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5082) (✓),  [Ohalot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5083) (18/134),  [Negaim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5084) (✓),   [Parah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5085) (✓),    [Taharot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5086) (✓),  [Mikvaot](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5087) (✓),  [Niddah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5088) (✓),   [Machshirin](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5089) (✓),    [Zavim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5090) (✓),     [Tevul Yom](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5091) (4/26),     [Yadayim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5092) (✓),  [Uktzim](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5093) (✓)

Answer (score 3):

### Chullin חולין : DONE!

[chulin-tractate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chulin-tractate)

The laws for the slaughtering of animals and birds for meat for ordinary as opposed to sacred use, and the Jewish dietary laws.

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Why is meat only kosher if a Jew slaughters the animal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81375/11501)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [What is the practical difference between nebelah and terefah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9112/11501)

  [Reason why pressing on an animal throat is forbidden during shechitah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93811/11501)
- X Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89388/
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Pregnant animals and kashrut](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84488/11501)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [What precautions (if any) are taken to avoid slaughtering a mother and child animal on the same day nowadays?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75303/11501)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Kisuy hadam: why sawdust?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6687/11501)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Meaning of the mitzvah to not eat Gid Hanashe](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78174/11501)
- X Chapter 8 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)
  [To shake milk that fell in a meat pot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99725/)
- X Chapter 9 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)
  [Which animals have tuma neveila?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37759/11501)
  [Is the partially generated animal dead?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/is-the-partially-generated-animal-dead)
- X Chapter 10 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [How could Avraham feed his guests tongue?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44081/11501)
- X Chapter 11 (2 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Question on discrepancy between Rambam and Gemara [regarding first shearing of sheep]](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/94765/11501)
- X Chapter 12 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Shiluach HaKen: why not “Hatzipor”](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11314/11501)

Answer (score 2):

### Berachot ברכות : DONE!

[tractate-brachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-brachot)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Mishna, Brakhot 2a: When the kohanim enter...where?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27560/759)
  [Mishna Brachos 1:3 , What should have Rabbi Tarfon done?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83451/759)
  [Circular reasoning in deriving the time that kohanim can eat terumah and the time that the evening Shema can be recited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101722/circular-reasoning-in-deriving-the-time-that-kohanim-can-eat-terumah-and-the-tim)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [How does a verse in Yirmiyahu prove that one should say "אני ה' אלהיכם אמת" without interruption](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/how-does-a-verse-in-yirmiyahu-prove-that-one-should-say-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99-%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9D-%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%AA-with)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  ['Aliyah an Isur 'Aseh? Even today?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18781/aliyah-an-isur-aseh-even-today)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Properly focusing attention on Hashem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93864/properly-focusing-attention-on-hashem)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  ["Hit him with a hammer until he pays attention!" Literally?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18911/hit-him-with-a-hammer-until-he-pays-attention-literally)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Why is the blessing of Mezonos not mentioned in the Mishnah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35040/why-is-the-blessing-of-mezonos-not-mentioned-in-the-mishnah)
  [How could Rav be disproved?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94687/how-could-rav-be-disproved)
- X Chapter 7 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [How can the Gemara bring a proof supporting רבינו from רבי אבא?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50931/how-can-the-gemara-bring-a-proof-supporting-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95-from-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%90%D7%91%D7%90)
- X Chapter 8 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Why do Beis Shammai and Beis Hillel argue twice regarding kiddush?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81258/why-do-beis-shammai-and-beis-hillel-argue-twice-regarding-kiddush)
- X Chapter 9 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Tefillat Shav in Mishna Masechet Berachot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90417/759)

Comment: Oh wait, was I not supposed to sign up for Chapter 1 since this is "not a live effort yet"?

Comment: @Alex Correct. On the other hand, hard to argue with *zerizim makdimim lemitzva*.

Comment: I have stored my files of chiddushim on Mishnayot as . E.g Mishnayot 03040201 is the first file of chiddushim on the second Mishna of the fourth chapter of masechet Nazir

Answer (score 2):

### Sukkah סוכה : DONE!

[masechet-sukkah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-sukkah)

*The laws of the sukkah, the four species, and the holiday of sukkot*

- X Chapter 1 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [What can I use for schach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-can-i-use-for-schach)

  [Why is bamboo kosher for schach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31046/why-is-bamboo-kosher-for-schach)
- X Chapter 2 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why does the Rambam change the wording of the Mishna in Succah 20b?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90133/759)
- X Chapter 3 (15 mishnayot) Claimed by: WAF

  [Derech g'dilasan: the requirement for mitzva objects to be used in the manner in which they grew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104460/3)
- X Chapter 4 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why do we beat the arava?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20263/why-do-we-beat-the-arava)
- X Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch  
  [Greatest Happiness on Earth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95519/)

Answer (score 2):

### Beitzah ביצה : DONE!

[tractate-beitza](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-beitza)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani
  [Parsing the mishna in Beitza 1:10](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31294/759)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani
  [Questions on the Bartenura in Beitza 2:3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31340/759)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo ani  
  [What does Rabban Shimon Ben Gamaliel mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108851/what-does-rabban-shimon-ben-gamaliel-mean)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani

  [Can I light a new fire on yom tov?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22289/can-i-light-a-new-fire-on-yom-tov)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani

  [Are marriages on Shabbat allowed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28338/are-marriages-on-shabbat-allowed)

Comment: @Lo Ani I put questions on chapters 4/5 to make it easier for you to finish but feel free to delete and replace if you prefer

Comment: Thanks @mbloch but aren’t there allowed to be more than one question per Perek?

Comment: Yes of course you can have many questions. I just didn't want to "impose" my questions but rather help you if you liked them. I'm trying to help accelerate the learning where I can

Answer (score 2):

### Sanhedrin סנהדרין - DONE!

[maseches-sanhedrin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-sanhedrin)

*The conduct of the beit din, with particular focus on death-penalty cases.*

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sanhedrin?lang=bi)

---

Note from [Monica Cellio](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio):

> I dedicate the learning of these 11 chapters of this *masechet* to the memories of 11 who died *al kiddush Hashem* in Pittsburgh: Joyce Fienberg, Richard Gottfried, Rose Mallinger, Jerry Rabinowitz, Cecil Rosenthal, David Rosenthal, Bernice Simon, Sylvan Simon, Daniel Stein, Melvin Wax, Irving Younger.

---

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How did Jerusalem get bigger without the Sanhedrin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52449)
  [Were there particular reasons to vow the value of a person?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59215/472)
  [Why does a small sanhedrin have 23 judges rather than 21?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105559/472)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [What happens if a Jewish king marries a 19th wife?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101310/)
  [Writing Sefer Torah for Melech (King)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28099/)
  [When can the brother of a man who died childless do neither yibbum nor chalitzah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105874/472)
  [How much of the sefer torah did the king read each day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28510/472)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Legally speaking, do we really have so few friends?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106049/472)
  [Changing the requirements of a monetary case](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71327/472)
  [Are Jewish Court Rulings subject to appeal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8616/472)
- X Chapter 4 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  ["Anyone who saves a life is as if he saved an entire world": Jewish life or any life?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/74049/)
  [How to make amends for my previous mistakes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15085/)
  [On "he who saved one life saves the world"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14719/)
  [Why is the talmud concerned about judges being swayed by each other only for capital cases?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106530/472)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why does a "hung jury" have to go through the motions of persuading someone to change his vote, instead of just acquitting?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106532/472)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How did the talmud's description of stoning work in practice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85254/)
  [Sanhedrin 6:6 - Halacha or common practice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79325/)
  [Why do the sages care if the condemned continues to deny his guilt to the end?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106684/472)
- X Chapter 7 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Sorcerers, wizards, warlocks... what are the differences?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85430/472)
  [How many sin-offerings are due for one who (unintentionally) sleeps with his mother while she's married to his father?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106758/472)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Becoming a "stubborn and rebellious child" - a question on Tosafot Yom Tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53501/)
  [The order of the wording of the Ben Sorrer U'Moreh source Mishnah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26457/)
  [Why would the Torah give us mitzvot that will never actually happen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99279/472)
  [Why does the mishna assume blind parents can't identify their son?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106834/472)
- X Chapter 9 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why was the kipa a justified way to execute criminals?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62678/)
  [From where do we learn that strangulation is the default execution method?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29248/472)
- X Chapter 10 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How can Eliyahu say that almost no one in the market has a share in Olam Haba?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40988/)
  [What Happens to People Who Don't Have a Portion in Olam Haba?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11644/)
  [Why does Gehazi have no share in the world to come?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30122/472)
- X Chapter 11 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [A rebellious elder is executed on the festival? How does that work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/107112/472)

Answer (score 2):

### Avodah Zara עבודה זרה : DONE!

[masecheth-avodah-zarah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masecheth-avodah-zarah)

The laws pertaining to Jews living amongst Gentiles, including regulations about the interaction between Jews and "idolaters".

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Is there a problem with buying a Christian a Christmas gift?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98957/is-there-a-problem-with-buying-a-christian-a-christmas-gift)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Who are the idolaters?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37747/who-are-the-idolaters)

  [Bishul Akum: now what?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14569/bishul-akum-now-what)

  [Is it Bishul Akum if a gentile boils non potable water?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106816/is-it-bishul-akum-if-a-gentile-boils-non-potable-water)

  [Kashrut of rennet for cheese & Difference between rennet and gelatin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29213/kashrut-of-rennet-for-cheese-difference-between-rennet-and-gelatin)
- X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) 
  [Name of avoda zara in the mishna?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100617/759)
- X Chapter 4 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Non-Jews and kosher wine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16577/non-jews-and-kosher-wine/16579#16579)
- X Chapter 5 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [May Jews sell wine to Christians for them to use in their religious ceremonies?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50750/may-jews-sell-wine-to-christians-for-them-to-use-in-their-religious-ceremonies/50751#50751)

Answer (score 2):

### Avot אבות: DONE!

[pirke-avot-ethicsof](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pirke-avot-ethicsof)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (18 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [How to go about finding a personal Rav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47398/how-to-go-about-finding-a-personal-rav)
  [Shammai - receive everyone with a pleasant countenance](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93974/shammai-receive-everyone-with-a-pleasant-countenance)
- X Chapter 2 (16 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [Do not separate yourself from the community: what exactly is the community?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18983/do-not-separate-yourself-from-the-community-what-exactly-is-the-community)
  [What's up with Rabbi Shimon ben Nesanel in Avos 2:10?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16085/whats-up-with-rabbi-shimon-ben-nesanel-in-avos-210)
- X Chapter 3 (18 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [How could Rebbi Zeira forcibly forget his learning?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33744/how-could-rebbi-zeira-forcibly-forget-his-learning)
- X Chapter 4 (22 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [What is the difference between Mitzvah Goreres Mitzvah and Schar Mitzvah Mitzvah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92323/what-is-the-difference-between-mitzvah-goreres-mitzvah-and-schar-mitzvah-mitzvah)
- X Chapter 5 (23 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex
  [what are the "Mishnah" and "Gemara" referenced in Pirkei Avot 5?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33524/what-are-the-mishnah-and-gemara-referenced-in-pirkei-avot-5)
  [Why does the Mishna not follow its own advice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17480/why-does-the-mishna-not-follow-its-own-advice)
  [Why is it important that God created the first pair of tongs?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48005/why-is-it-important-that-god-created-the-first-pair-of-tongs)
  [What's the connection between Avraham and Bilaam?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29494/whats-the-connection-between-avraham-and-bilaam)
  [Who is the author of the 5th parek of pirkei avot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/79578/who-is-the-author-of-the-5th-parek-of-pirkei-avot)
  [Pirkei Avot 5:17 - Did they mean Bet Hillel and Bet Shamai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73569/16706)

Comment: [If you're wondering why only five are listed....](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84858)

Answer (score 2):

### Kinnim קנים : DONE!

[tractate-kinnim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-kinnim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [How to bring kinnim after having mixed up birds](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101609/how-to-bring-kinnim-after-having-mixed-up-birds)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Kinnim mix-ups with different numbers of pairs in each group](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101803/kinnim-mix-ups-with-different-numbers-of-pairs-in-each-group)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Rule (Ze haKlal) in Kinnim 3:1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102060/rule-ze-haklal-in-kinnim-31)

Answer (score 2):

### Mikvaot מקואות : DONE!

[maseches-mikvaos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-mikvaos)

The laws pertaining to the building and maintenance of a mikvah, a Jewish ritual bath.

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Can mikvah water become tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76946/11501)

  [Can a lake be used as mikvah during the day for niddah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/91739/11501)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Sofek d'rabbanan by tevillah of an isha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27635/11501)
- X Chapter 3 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Can you use a pool for a mens mikvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44267/11501)
- X Chapter 4 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Can I make a mikvah using artificial rain?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26921/11501)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Dipping in a basket vs. on a bench](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68698/11501)
- X Chapter 6 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Mikvah with three additional chambers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31795/11501)
- X Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Can one Tovel dishes in snow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23448/11501)
- X Chapter 8 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Loosely holding utensils in a mikve - halacha development](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105100/11501)

  [Why don't men go to the mikveh after relations?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69956/11501)
- X Chapter 9 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Are lice considered a chatzitza?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33924/11501)

  [Hair dyeing for women](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14316/11501)

  [Nail polish chatzitzah and mikveh immersion](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56941/11501)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Unclean due to an organ transplant, in the context of the rebuilt temple](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71481/11501)

Answer (score 2):

### Niddah נידה : DONE!

[maseches-niddah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-niddah)

Laws of a Niddah, a woman either during her menstrual cycle or shortly after having given birth.

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Dr. Shmuel 

  [Why is pekida used instead of bedika?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103896/)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why can't one have marital relations with the light on?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57184/why-cant-one-have-marital-relations-with-the-light-on)
- X Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Is a Jew permitted to have an abortion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/39015/is-a-jew-permitted-to-have-an-abortion/39025#39025) *
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 

  [How does a woman become a zava?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84576/how-does-a-woman-become-a-zava)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Can a 9 year old do Yibbum?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/can-a-9-year-old-do-yibbum)

  [Neder of 11 year old girl](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31789/neder-of-11-year-old-girl)
- X Chapter 6 (14 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Signs of a Kosher Fish](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70687/759)
- X Chapter 7 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [If a Niddah spits on you are you Impure?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47798/if-a-niddah-spits-on-you-are-you-impure)
- X Chapter 8 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Kesamim found on a tattoo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97836/kesamim-found-on-a-tattoo)
- X Chapter 9 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Is there such a thing as "Veset Halom"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36506/is-there-such-a-thing-as-veset-halom)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [What's the reason for moch dachuk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77648/whats-the-reason-for-moch-dachuk)

<sup>* the last mishna in that chapter links the development of a fetus with 40 days, a number mentioned in some opinions on abortions</sup>

Answer (score 1):

### Demai דמאי: DONE!

[maseches-demai](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-demai)

The tractate deals with produce that isn't known to have been properly tithed.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demai_(tractate))
[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Demai.1.1)

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Why do you need a chazakah and a sefeik sefeikah in Demai 1:1?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80964/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Why can you buy dry fruit from an Am Ha'aretz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81308/1569)
  [Why did Rabbis stay away from Amei Haaretz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14704/1569)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Why is this Mishnah repeated regarding backing out of sales?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81984/1569)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [When did kosher bakeries, restaurants, etc. start requiring supervision?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6543/1569)
- X Chapter 5 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Mishna Demai 5:11: why can't you take teruma from vadai on demai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29467/759)
  [Why take t'ruma? Aren't people trusted to do so?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76981/1569)
- X Chapter 6 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [What should one who inherits forbidden items do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81225/1569)
- X Chapter 7 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Did Rabban Shim'on ben Gamli'el accept the stipulation of the court?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101700/1569)

Answer (score 1):

### Terumot תרומות: DONE!

[maseches-terumos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-terumos)

The laws about the portion of produce that is supposed to be given to a priest.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terumot)
[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Terumot.1)

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Becoming Deaf and Mute](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26409/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Is reading an email written and sent to you on Shabbat or a holiday permitted?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76664/1569)
  [Having hana'ah from a melacha done on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67808/1569)
  [Can you derive benefit from another Jew's melacha if it happened a long time ago?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44693/1569)
  [Benefiting from a Jew's meizid melacha on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101798/11532)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Is there a prohibition to eat produce before bikkurim (first fruits) have been separated?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45360/1569)
- X Chapter 4 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Tithing Precision](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3043/1569)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:     b a
  [What's the difference between יאכלו נקודים and יתחלקו לעסות (in תרומות פ״ה)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67854/1569)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:     b a
  [Why the principal (money) is called Keren?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96993/1569)
- X Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [How can we be lenient in a case of mixed up teruma?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103294/1569)
- X Chapter 8 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Covering containers of water](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31855/1569)
  [If pirates demand you turn someone over, why can't you choose the person already subject to the death penalty?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92196/1569)
  [kill him or I kill both of you](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99816/1569)
- X Chapter 9 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:    b a
  [Can meat grown from living cells be kosher? Is it eiver min hachai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69617/1569)
- X Chapter 10 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by:  b a
  [Can one use terumah to light a stove?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30450/759)
- X Chapter 11 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Dew distinct from water among the shiva mashkim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1294/1569)

Comment: I must be missing something here. Where is Terumos discussed at all in the chapter 2 questions?

Comment: @DonielF They relate to 2:3 but the questions don't discuss the mishna specifically

Answer (score 1):

### Chalah חלה: DONE!

[maseches-challa](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-challa)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Joel K
  [To what grains do the laws of yoshon apply?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49070)
  [Is there a minimum amount of dough to separate challah without a bracha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-there-a-minimum-amount-of-dough-to-separate-challah-without-a-bracha)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Joel K
  [Wheat brought from the Diaspora to Israel: biblical or rabbinic challah-obligation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107084/wheat-brought-from-the-diaspora-to-israel-biblical-or-rabbinic-challah-obligati)
- X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Joel K
  [Why does dough containing a small amount of terumah become exempt from challah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107099/why-does-dough-containing-a-small-amount-of-terumah-become-exempt-from-challah)
- X Chapter 4 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:  Joel K
  [What were they thinking following contradictory leniencies in Challah 4:7?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86664/what-were-they-thinking-following-contradictory-leniencies-in-challah-47)
  [Do contemporary non-Ashkenazim give challah to a kohen in chutz la’aretz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96487/do-contemporary-non-ashkenazim-give-challah-to-a-kohen-in-chutz-la-aretz)

Answer (score 1):

### Pesachim פסחים: DONE!

[maseches-pesachim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-pesachim)

The laws of the Jewish holiday Passover as well as the Passover lamb offering. The first four chapters cover the laws of chametz, chapters 5–9 discuss the laws of the Passover lamb offering, and the tenth and final chapter discusses the order of the Passover seder, as well as the law of pairs.

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Areas of Cellar Accessed by Butler](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81394/areas-of-cellar-accessed-by-butler)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

    [Can you eat חמץ שעבר עליו פסח?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/54051/can-you-eat-%D7%97%D7%9E%D7%A5-%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95-%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [what should be done to chametz on a shabbat day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70324/what-should-be-done-to-chametz-on-a-shabbat-day/70326#70326)
- X Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Are there still communities that eat roasted meat Seder night?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56745/are-there-still-communities-that-eat-roasted-meat-seder-night)

  [Is there a custom not to eat roasted chicken at the Seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27077/is-there-a-custom-not-to-eat-roasted-chicken-at-the-seder)
- X Chapter 5 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [How many people brought sacrifices to the tabernacle at the same time?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86633/how-many-people-brought-sacrifices-to-the-tabernacle-at-the-same-time/86651#86651)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why eat korbanot satiated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71538/why-eat-korbanot-satiated/71539#71539)
- X Chapter 7 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11532/heshy)
  [What was the purpose of the hora'as sha'ah to burn the goat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101407/11532)
- X Chapter 8 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11532/heshy)
  [Why does the servant register on a Pesach by himself?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101543/11532)
- X Chapter 9 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11532/heshy)
  [Why can you put the Chagiga on the table with the Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101955/11532)
- X Chapter 10 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: [popularisntright](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5459/popularisntright) with his daughter
  a good fraction of [passover-seder-hagada](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passover-seder-hagada)
  to pick one example: [What is parperet hapat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102021/5459)

[PTIJ section](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5109/11532)

> Chapter 1
>  [PTIJ: Spontaneous Combustion on Erev Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100434/11532)
>  Chapter 8
>  [PTIJ: Why were people burned for mixing up their Karban Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101013/11532)

Comment: @Heshy did you mean to sign up for chap 9 or not? It has your name but isn't marked off.

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight yeah I didn't get a chance to ask a question yet.  If you have one go ahead and ask it.

Comment: @Heshy I didn't realize the X didn't come till it was finished. I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

### Yoma יומא : DONE!

[masechet-yoma](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-yoma)

Covers the service of the *kohein gadol* on Yom Kippur.

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How does the kohein gadol's substitute wife work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/how-does-the-kohein-gadols-substitute-wife-work)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why did they cancel the kohein races over an isolated incident?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47851/)
- X Chapter 3 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why was it important that the smoke from the ketoret went up in a straight column?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/92308/)
  [Were the בגדי לבן‎ 30 ‎מנה in weight or value?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31613)
  [How could anybody confuse moonlight and sunlight?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103999/how-could-anybody-confuse-moonlight-and-sunlight)
- X Chapter 4 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [What is the purpose of the goat for Azazel, as opposed to conventional offerings?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104507/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-goat-for-azazel-as-opposed-to-conventional-offerings)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How did the High Priest get to the position between the two staves of the ark on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85461/how-did-the-high-priest-get-to-the-position-between-the-two-staves-of-the-ark-on)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [When beseeching God, why does the kohein gadol say "the torah of Moshe" and not "your torah"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105020/when-beseeching-god-why-does-the-kohein-gadol-say-the-torah-of-moshe-and-not)
  [Why do they offer food and drink to the one leading the goat for Azazel, instead of replacing the person if he can't complete the task?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105021/why-do-they-offer-food-and-drink-to-the-one-leading-the-goat-for-azazel-instead)
- X Chapter 7 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Seeing the Kohen Gadol or seeing the burning of the bull in the Mikdash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95549/)
- X Chapter 8 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why is "affliction of the soul" interpreted differently in two places?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91328/)
  [Are we supposed to know which transgressions are light or severe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105024/are-we-supposed-to-know-which-transgressions-are-light-or-severe)

Answer (score 1):

### Rosh HaShanah ראש השנה - DONE!

[maseches-rosh-hashana](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-rosh-hashana)

Rules concerning the calendar year, together with a description of the inauguration of the months, laws on the form and use of the shofar and laws related to the religious services during the holiday of Rosh Hashanah.

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 

  [Why didn't they send messengers for Rosh Chodesh Shevat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98320/) 

  [Why is Rosh Chodesh Nisan for kings - not Rosh Hashana?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86506/)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Jeremy Schnittman
  [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97216/11532) to [Why does the Torah list all of Esav's Tribes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97173/11532)

  [Why do קידוש החדש על פי הראייה?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81203/why-do-%d7%a7%d7%99%d7%93%d7%95%d7%a9-%d7%94%d7%97%d7%93%d7%a9-%d7%a2%d7%9c-%d7%a4%d7%99-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%90%d7%99%d7%99%d7%94)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Shofar from an extinct animal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30967/shofar-from-an-extinct-animal)

  [Shofar Certification](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/shofar-certification)

  [Regulations on shofar production](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/regulations-on-shofar-production)
- X Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 

  [What prompted the absent-Sanhedrin-head decree in Rosh Hashana 4:4?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82071/)

Answer (score 1):

### Taanit תענית : DONE!

[masechet-taanis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-taanis)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani
  [How much time passes before we understand that the drought hasn’t ended?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105083/how-much-time-passes-before-we-understand-that-the-drought-hasn-t-ended)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani
  [Could the anshei beit av wash their clothes and cut their hair on Thursday?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105126/could-the-anshei-beit-av-wash-their-clothes-and-cut-their-hair-on-thursday)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:  Lo Ani
  [What is the symbolism of Choni Ha'Magel's circle?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34050/)
- X Chapter 4 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  Lo Ani
  [Dancing on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31602/)
  [Why were there so many Karbanos Eitzim in Av, and so few during the rest of the year?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94313/why-were-there-so-many-karbanos-eitzim-in-av-and-so-few-during-the-rest-of-the)

Answer (score 1):

### Megilah מגילה - DONE!

[tractate-megillah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-megillah)

The laws of Purim, commentary to the Book of Esther, laws concerning the public reading of the Torah and other communal synagogue practices.

- X Chapter 1 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 
  [Trying to understand Mishnah Megilla 1:4](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68177/)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 
  [Are you Yotzei Mikrah Megillah if you're spacing out?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26567/)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: YEZ 
  [We need ten consolers; why not ten mourners?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100591)
- X Chapter 4 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch 
  [Megillah 4.6 -- Why can't the blind recite the Shema with their benedictions (according to R. Judah)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75242/)

Answer (score 1):

### Chaggigah חגיגה : DONE!

[tractate-chagiga](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-chagiga)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo ani
  [Irrelevant case in Chagiga 1:7?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103302/irrelevant-case-in-chagiga-17)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo ani
  [The mishnah of four things not to look at](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100891/)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  Lo ani
  [Why do we need the second reason?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105052/)

Answer (score 1):

### Yevamot יבמות : DONE!

[masechet-yevamot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-yevamot)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Yibum and Chalitzah: stringency or leniency?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48433/11532)
  [Yevamot Relationship Chart](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65215/11532)
  [Why am I told specifically not to uncover my father's nakedness?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45980/11532)
  [Polygamous rabbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103212/11532)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  ["She may marry any Jewish man"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95369/11532)
  [Jewish man serve on Beis Din for woman he's dating](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103354/11532)
- X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Understanding the Rambam's commentary to Yevamos 3:7 and 3:9](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104055/11532)
- X Chapter 4 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Understanding Yevamot 4:13's proof of who, exactly, is a mamzer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29928/understanding-yevamot-413s-proof-of-who-exactly-is-a-mamzer)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
   [Why "How so?" in Y'vamos 5:2?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101429/why-how-so-in-yvamos-52)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Why the story of a kohen gadol marrying a widow (יבמות ו:ד)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101453/why-the-story-of-a-kohen-gadol-marrying-a-widow-%D7%99%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%93) 
   [Invalidating women from the priesthood and from terumah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28565/invalidating-women-from-the-priesthood-and-from-terumah) 
   [Spitting at the High Priest on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26774)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Why is the case of the near-simultaneous deaths in Y'vamos chapter 7?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101520/why-is-the-case-of-the-near-simultaneous-deaths-in-yvamos-chapter-7) 
   [Invalidating women from the priesthood and from terumah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28565/invalidating-women-from-the-priesthood-and-from-terumah)
- X Chapter 8 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [If someone had a family tradition that he came from an Edomite, would he be allowed to marry a Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/if-someone-had-a-family-tradition-that-he-came-from-an-edomite-would-he-be-allo)
- X Chapter 9 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Spitting at the High Priest on Yom Kippur](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26774/759) 
   [Why "the" widow in Y'vamos chapter 9?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101646/why-the-widow-in-yvamos-chapter-9)
- X Chapter 10 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why can the sister-in-law return to her husband according to R. Yosi? Isn't she forbidden to the husband and to the adulterer? (Y'vamos 10:4)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101755/170)
- X Chapter 11 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Estate of a convert whose only possible heir is just that: only a possible heir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101890/170)
- X Chapter 12 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [How does נעלו exclude a סנדל מסוליים?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102087/170)
- X Chapter 13 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Does בית שמאי hold a second מיאון effective?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102088/170)
- X Chapter 14 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [One case is missing from פרק חרש שנשא](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102167/170)
- X Chapter 15 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Do we force someone along the דרך מוציאתו מידי עבירה, according to R. Akiva?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103253/170)
- X Chapter 16 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98408/2

Answer (score 1):

### Nedarim נדרים: DONE!

[tractate-nedarim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-nedarim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Why list קונם and קונס explicitly in Kol Nidrei but not other Kinuyim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98134/)
  [What are the different types of oaths mentioned in Kol Nidre?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95177/170)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Eating Matzah of Tevel or Heqdesh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27784/759)
- X Chapter 3 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Connection between the eulogy of Shaul by Dovid and Nedarim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98684/)
  [Why is "any promise I will promise" where it is in N'darim chapter 3?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104627/170)
- X Chapter 4 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why do we care about a cow loan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104628/170)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/4311/170
- X Chapter 6 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is garlic forbidden to one who forswore mikpa?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104765/170)
- X Chapter 7 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Large scale hydroponics and Shmita](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/61611/170)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Nedarim 61 and multiple year neder](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83559/170)
- X Chapter 9 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Annulling nedarim on the basis of noladim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28410/759)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Do fathers revoke all their daughters' vows right before they turn 12.5?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103298/11532)
- X Chapter 11 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  ["Yours once you've converted it to food and put it in your mouth"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105016/170)

Answer (score 1):

### Nazir נזיר - DONE

[masechet-nazir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-nazir)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Checkmate

  [What did the Nazir's death add to the story?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104367/what-did-the-nazirs-death-add-to-the-story?r=SearchResults&s=1|184.7650)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Checkmate

  [Why the Minimum Nazirship Length?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106353/why-the-minimum-nazirship-length)
- X Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [How is a kohen allowed to go outside Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15273/170)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Minhag for married women to cover their hair in bed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48375/178)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Should Jepthah have sacrificed his daughter?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34551/170)
- X Chapter 6 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why are Nazirite restrictions not tailor-made to the individual?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104983/170)
- X Chapter 7 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Allowing the forbidden for the sake of a Mitzvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27526/170)
- X Chapter 8 (2 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is one who touched doubtful Tumah in a public domain considered Tahor?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80727/170)
- X Chapter 9 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How was Shmuel permitted to kill Agag?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36350/170)

Answer (score 1):

### Sotah סוטה : DONE!

[tractate-sotah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-sotah)

Most of this tractate is about the *sotah*, the woman accused of adultery who drinks a special potion to prove her innocence (or not).  See [Bamidbar 5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0405.htm):11-31.

The tractate also discusses declarations that can be said in any language (like the *sotah*'s oath), exemptions from (optional) wars, the ceremony in which a heifer's neck is broken to atone for a murder between two cities, and the ends of various practices.

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Confessing to Adultery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29100/confessing-to-adultery)
  [What is the amount of time a suspected woman needs to be secluded to be considered a Sotah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98948/what-is-the-amount-of-time-a-suspected-woman-needs-to-be-secluded-to-be-consider)
  [What happens if the accused sotah doesn't consent to the ritual?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28678/472)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Does a sotah warning from a couples first marriage carry into their second marriage?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84851/472) (I found this question by starting to ask it!)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [A female thief is not sold to make restitution -- so what happens instead?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101794/472)
  [How early in the process can the accused sotah refuse to drink?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101795/472)
- X Chapter 4 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [If only a married woman can be a sotah, why does a non-spouse have authority to warn her?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102078/472)
  [Can anyone warn a man's wife to give her the status of a sotah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89160/472)
  [Can a husband 'un-warn' his wife to prevent her from becoming a sotah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84500/472)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Are there any merits which delay the adulterer's explosion?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88966/are-there-any-merits-which-delay-the-adulterers-explosion)
  [What happens if the accused sotah did commit adultery, but not with the man she was warned about?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102113/what-happens-if-the-accused-sotah-did-commit-adultery-but-not-with-the-man-she)
- X Chapter 6 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Who are "the women who twist yarn by the moon"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102115/who-are-the-women-who-twist-yarn-by-the-moon)
- X Chapter 7 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [For things that can be said in any language, how fully must you understand the language?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103239/for-things-that-can-be-said-in-any-language-how-fully-must-you-understand-the-l)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Does any ongoing transgression exempt one from going to war?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103241/does-any-ongoing-transgression-exempt-one-from-military-service)
  [Historically, were women trained for obligatory wars? Or did they serve some other military function?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103275/historically-were-women-trained-for-obligatory-wars-or-did-they-serve-some-oth)
- X Chapter 9 (15 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [In the time of the mishna, were there Jewish cities without courts?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103274/in-the-time-of-the-mishna-were-there-jewish-cities-without-courts)

Answer (score 1):

### Gittin גיטין: Done!

[maseches-gitin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-gitin)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5702/170
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8984/170
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Legal status of one sentenced to death?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106186/170)
- X Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [why is a half `Eved` not freed automatically](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83827/)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Could a Kohen become liable for disqualifying a sacrifice?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99162/170)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How can a convert be a Na'arah Me'orasah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101437/170)
- X Chapter 7 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How could David lie with Bat Sheva if she had a Safek Get?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27910/170)
- X Chapter 8 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26647/170
- X Chapter 9 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is it often Claimed a Forced Get is Invalid?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51224/170)

Answer (score 1):

### Kidushin קידושין: DONE!

[maseches-kiddushin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kiddushin)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Is a car considered movable or immovable property?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101677/)
  [Can you acquire land merely by using it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70147/)
  [Beis Shammai's dinar for kiddushin - philosophy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17146/)
  ["A y'vama acquires herself through chalitza", really?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106657/170)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Money obtained by selling Tikrovet avoda zara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99648/170)
- X Chapter 3 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/105417/170
- X Chapter 4 (14 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why do the best of doctors go to Gehinnom according to the Maharsha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84807/)
  [If someone never met their father, but has various information about him (e.g last name, profession etc.), are they a shetuki?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71582/)

Answer (score 1):

### Makkot מכות : DONE!

[maseches-makos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-makos)

Covers cities of refuge and the penalty of lashes.

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [How is the law in a case of multiple edim zomemim justified by Chachomim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103355/1569)
  [Did courts ever execute?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7739/)
  [Is there a difference between מכות and מלקות?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101593/)
  [Why would a third witness ever testify?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105279/472)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Rishon who holds killing in an upward motion is more negligent](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94484/)
  [How did accidental killers sustain themselves while living in the cities of refuge?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105280/472)
  [Why do accidental killers sent to arei miklat go free after the Kohen Gadol dies?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9417/472)
  [Exile the teacher also to the city of refuge?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101441/472)
  [What if Someone Accidentally Killed Someone in an Ir Miklat (City of Refuge)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26793/472)
- X Chapter 3 (16 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Does a person who wets or soils himself during lashes still receive the kapparah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103963/472)
  [Sending away the mother bird, mitzvah at the onset?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85169/472)
  [Lashes for owning chametz when the Pesach is brought](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84026/472)
  [Doctor's mistake and homicide](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28956/472)

Answer (score 1):

### Horayot הוריות : DONE!

[masechet-horayot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-horayot)

Errors in courts' or individuals' decisions, when and which offerings are brought as a result, special rules for kings and high priests, precedence in offerings, and precedence in saving people.

[Horayot at Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Horayot.1?lang=bi)

- X Chapter 1 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why does the mishna prescribe an indirect measure of whether somebody knew about a court ruling?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103453/why-does-the-mishna-prescribe-an-indirect-measure-of-whether-somebody-knew-about)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why does the atonement for impurity in the Temple take so many different forms?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70918/why-does-the-atonement-for-impurity-in-the-temple-take-so-many-different-forms)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Monica Cellio
  [Why would becoming king or kohein gadol exempt one from atoning for past sins?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103595/why-would-becoming-king-or-kohein-gadol-exempt-one-from-atoning-for-past-sins)

Answer (score 1):

### Menachot מנחות - DONE!

[maseches-menachos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-menachos)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Precautions to avoid adulterated handful of meal offering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102037/precautions-to-avoid-adulterated-handful-of-meal-offering)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102121/where-is-an-introduction-to-the-concept-of-מתיר-regarding-offerings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102121/where-is-an-introduction-to-the-concept-of-%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A8-regarding-offerings)
- X Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [If Moshe received ALL future Torah at Har Sinai, why didn't he understand R' Akiva's shiur (Menachos 29b)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100671/if-moshe-received-all-future-torah-at-har-sinai-why-didnt-he-understand-r-aki)
- X Chapter 4 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why may one not wear Tefillin after Shekiah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97155/why-may-one-not-wear-tefillin-after-shekiah)
  [Head tefillin - how serious is it when the divisions between the individual scrolls are split?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73970/head-tefillin-how-serious-is-it-when-the-divisions-between-the-individual-scro)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why not say mishna (M'nachos 61) means to exclude R' Y'huda?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Who said to whom? (M'nachos 70)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28468/who-said-to-whom-mnachos-70)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Understanding how the omer was sifted](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/understanding-how-the-omer-was-sifted)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Is grain from outside Israel usable for offerings or not?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103470/is-grain-from-outside-israel-usable-for-offerings-or-not)
- X Chapter 9 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [What type of olive oil was used for the shemen hamishcha (Anointing oil)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68527/what-type-of-olive-oil-was-used-for-the-shemen-hamishcha-anointing-oil)
  [No leaning for communal offerings? But there is!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/116742/170)
- X Chapter 10 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Who got to have the leftover flour from the Omer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103861/who-got-to-have-the-leftover-flour-from-the-omer)
- X Chapter 11 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [What are the reasons for the unique shape of the Lechem Hapanim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80589/what-are-the-reasons-for-the-unique-shape-of-the-lechem-hapanim)
- X Chapter 12 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [If someone knowingly designates a Korban Mincha with barley, does he offer with wheat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48586/if-someone-knowingly-designates-a-korban-mincha-with-barley-does-he-offer-with)
- X Chapter 13 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73781/2) to [Birkat Kohanim for a Kohen who was very far from Judaism and decided to be a good Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73780/birkat-kohanim-for-a-kohen-who-was-very-far-from-judaism-and-decided-to-be-a-goo)

Answer (score 1):

### Tamid תמיד - DONE!

[maseches-tamid](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-tamid)

The Temple service for the daily morning and evening sacrifice, known as the Korban Tamid, in accordance with the Torah (Ex 29:38-42 and Num 28:2-8). ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kodashim))

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Kohanim slept on guard?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53915/kohanim-slept-on-guard)
  [Why does the ash-clearing kohen get a reminder of where the shovel is?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101334/why-does-the-ash-clearing-kohen-get-a-reminder-of-where-the-shovel-is)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why specifically branches as firewood on the Altar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101395/)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [is there a list of the 93 vessels used in the temple daily?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91257/is-there-a-list-of-the-93-vessels-used-in-the-temple-daily)
  [Why was the side door to the hechal unlocked so oddly?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33788/9682)
  [Where did the incense-altar sweeper get his broom from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71277/where-did-the-incense-altar-sweeper-get-his-broom-from)
  [Was the noise from the Temple really that loud?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53302/was-the-noise-from-the-temple-really-that-loud)
  [Michvar goats' sneezing from Jerusalem incense?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11315)
- X Chapter 4 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [How is the small side of a lamb the "large" side?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66826/how-is-the-small-side-of-a-lamb-the-large-side)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why didn't kohanim undress themselves?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35555/why-didnt-kohanim-undress-themselves)
  [Why cover coals in the Temple, and what if the cover was needed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35556/why-cover-coals-in-the-temple-and-what-if-the-cover-was-needed)
  [What did the Kohanim do if there was nobody who hadn't already done the K'toret?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73522/)
- X Chapter 6 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why does the incense offerer get a chosen buddy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101840/why-does-the-incense-offerer-get-a-buddy)
- X Chapter 7 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [How and why would they grasp the Kohen Gadol's shoulder stones?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101842/how-and-why-would-they-grasp-the-kohen-gadols-shoulder-stones)
  [In what sense will the world to come be a Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81278/9682)

Answer (score 1):

### Kelim כלים: DONE!

[maseches-keilim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-keilim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Is a metzorah oleh l'regel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16501/is-a-metzorah-oleh-lregel)
  [Non-Jews vs Zavim with respect to entering the Temple](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102062/non-jews-vs-zavim-with-respect-to-entering-the-temple)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31449) to [Does handling dinosaur bones make one Tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31445/does-handling-dinosaur-bones-make-one-tamei/)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/28140) to [Why do plastic bags and not fuselages protect against impurity?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28134/why-do-plastic-bags-and-not-fuselages-protect-against-impurity/)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53912) to [Where in halachah does it say that one is forbidden to go onto the Har HaBayis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53902/where-in-halachah-does-it-say-that-one-is-forbidden-to-go-onto-the-har-habayis/)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Is a paper Keili susceptible to tumah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84371/is-a-paper-keili-susceptible-to-tumah)
  [Is a wooden knife מקבל טומאה?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47492/is-a-wooden-knife-%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%9C-%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%94)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [What does שם כלי mean?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103412/what-does-%D7%A9%D7%9D-%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99-mean)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77609) to [How does waterproofing the Ark from the inside help practically?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77208/how-does-waterproofing-the-ark-from-the-inside-help-practically/)
- X Chapter 4 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Can air-dried earthenware become tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103526/can-air-dried-earthenware-become-tamei)
- X Chapter 5 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [How does tumah work in the sale of an oven between a householder and a baker?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103842/how-does-tumah-work-in-the-sale-of-an-oven-between-a-householder-and-a-baker)
- X Chapter 6 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Two supports for a stove: which one "counts"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103851/two-supports-for-a-stove-which-one-counts)
  [Does clay used as a foundation count as clay or as the ground?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103852/does-clay-used-as-a-foundation-count-as-clay-or-as-the-ground)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why is the halacha according to R. Meir against R. Shimon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103975/why-is-the-halacha-according-to-r-meir-against-r-shimon)
- X Chapter 8 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why use/repeat this phrase in the mishna?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104369/why-use-repeat-this-phrase-in-the-mishna)
- X Chapter 9 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why record retracted opinions in the mishnah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/why-record-retracted-opinions-in-the-mishnah)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why does an upside-down sealed pot save everything below it from tumah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/why-does-an-upside-down-sealed-pot-save-everything-below-it-from-tumah)
- X Chapter 11 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why does the Chazon Ish not allow supporting the schach with nailed planks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93193/why-does-the-chazon-ish-not-allow-supporting-the-schach-with-nailed-planks)
- X Chapter 12 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why do unfinished wooden utensils have a different law than unfinished metal utensils?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104680/why-do-unfinished-wooden-utensils-have-a-different-law-than-unfinished-metal-ute)
- X Chapter 13 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Is coral a kind of wood?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105034/is-coral-a-kind-of-wood)
- X Chapter 14 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93289) to [Why sprinkle on the third day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93278/why-sprinkle-on-the-third-day/)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48933) to [What did they do for shiurim before modern measurements?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48932/what-did-they-do-for-shiurim-before-modern-measurements)
- X Chapter 15 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Tumah of liquids: a question on Bartenura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105099/tumah-of-liquids-a-question-on-bartenura)
- X Chapter 16 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Tumah after deciding not to "finish" an object](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105214/tumah-after-deciding-not-to-finish-an-object)
- X Chapter 17 (17 mishnayot) Claimed by: Dr. Shmuel
  [Halachic measures](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89019/halachic-measures)
  [Have the measurements for tumah changed throughout the ages?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106434/have-the-measurements-for-tumah-changed-throughout-the-ages)
- X Chapter 18 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why compare zimmun to the tumah of broken/repaired vessels?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105407/why-compare-zimmun-to-the-tumah-of-broken-repaired-vessels)
- X Chapter 19 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Odd choice of language in Keilim 19:4 and 28:6](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105534/odd-choice-of-language-in-keilim-194-and-286)
- X Chapter 20 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why isn't Keilim 20:6 reckoned amongst the stringencies of Beit Hillel and the leniencies of Beit Shammai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105566/why-isnt-keilim-206-reckoned-amongst-the-stringencies-of-beit-hillel-and-the-l)
- X Chapter 21 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why are a plow's metal rings used to connect oxen considered integral?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106448/why-are-a-plows-metal-rings-used-to-connect-oxen-considered-integral)
- X Chapter 22 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [How can Bet Shamai argue on Shamai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96336/how-can-bet-shamai-argue-on-shamai)
- X Chapter 23 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Tumah of stuffed objects](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105740/tumah-of-stuffed-objects)
- X Chapter 24 (17 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Can toys become tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105828/can-toys-become-tamei)
- X Chapter 25 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why be stringent on Rabbinic tumah for sacrificial meat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105877/why-be-stringent-on-rabbinic-tumah-for-sacrificial-meat)
- X Chapter 26 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why is a leather belt susceptible to tumah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106011/why-is-a-leather-belt-susceptible-to-tumah)
  [Why is a tanner's intention not effective to induce susceptibility to tumah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106013/why-is-a-tanners-intention-not-effective-to-induce-susceptibility-to-tumah)
- X Chapter 27 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why do certain cloth combinations become susceptible to tumah while others don't?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106292/why-do-certain-cloth-combinations-become-susceptible-to-tumah-while-others-dont)
- X Chapter 28 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Which manuscript of the Mishna did the Bartenura check?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66746/759)
- X Chapter 29 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why does Rambam change the list of items in Keilim 29:2 that combine for tumah and hazayah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106433/why-does-rambam-change-the-list-of-items-in-keilim-292-that-combine-for-tumah-a)
- X Chapter 30 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Who compiled tractate Keilim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106432/who-compiled-tractate-keilim)

Answer (score 1):

### Negaim נגעים - DONE!

[maseches-negaim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-negaim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [How do different colours combine to exempt from impurity? (Nega'im 1:3)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102034/how-do-different-colours-join-to-exempt-from-impurity-negaim-13)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Asymmetry of R. Meir's times to inspect tzara'at (Nega'im 2:2)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/102038/asymmetry-of-r-meirs-times-to-inspect-tzaraat-negaim-22)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [German and Ethiopian Jews in the time of the Mishna?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70210/)
- X Chapter 4 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [R. Akiva's opinion regarding tzara'at that expands and contracts (Negai'm 4:7-8)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103293/r-akivas-opinion-regarding-tzaraat-that-expands-and-contracts-negaim-47-8)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Why are doubtful nega'im (generally) pure? (Nega'im 5:1)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103697/why-are-doubtful-negaim-generally-pure-negaim-51)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [What does R. Meir hold about the case in Nega'im 6:2?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103889/what-does-r-meir-hold-about-the-case-in-negaim-62)
- X Chapter 7 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Why do mishnayot teach historical halachot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/103970/why-do-mishnayot-teach-historical-halachot)
- X Chapter 8 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Paradox in Tzarat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70185/paradox-in-tzarat)
- X Chapter 9 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by:  [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Why is the possibility of being able to eventually rule a nega' impure necessary in order to quarantine it initially?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104153/why-is-the-possibility-of-being-able-to-eventually-rule-a-nega-impure-necessary)
- X Chapter 10 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Understanding a qal vechomer in the Mishna](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69194/759)
- X Chapter 11 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [A question on the Mishna, Negaim 11:7](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70211/759)
- X Chapter 12 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Not Negah but Like a Negah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6761/not-negah-but-like-a-negah) 
  [Can one say to the Kohen, "A nega appeared on my body"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104516/can-one-say-to-the-kohen-a-nega-appeared-on-my-body)
  [Why would the Torah give us mitzvot that will never actually happen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99279/why-would-the-torah-give-us-mitzvot-that-will-never-actually-happen)
- X Chapter 13 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [What's the difference between a house imparting impurity from the inside and to one entering it? (Nega'im 13:4)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104848/whats-the-difference-between-a-house-imparting-impurity-from-the-inside-and-to)
- X Chapter 14 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Joel K](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/14850/joel-k)
  [Razor used by Leviyim, Nezirim and Lepers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99284/razor-used-by-leviyim-nezirim-and-leper-s)

Answer (score 1):

### Parah פרה: DONE!

[maseches-parah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-parah)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Where did the first parah adumah come from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75975/11532)
  [Is it only sheep that have a 30-day period between their periods of acceptability as a korban?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108412/4940)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49196/4940) to [How can a parah adumah be validated?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49195/4940)
- X Chapter 3 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Which of the 9 Parah Adumahs that have existed was from Dama ben Nesina?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105613/4940)
  [Red heifer ashes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83803/4940)
  [Why was it so important that the Kohen preparing the Parah Adumah be a tevul yom?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93259/759)
  [Using a robot "puppet" for matters requiring purity](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71428/4940)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/56838/4940) to [How Was the Red Heifer Water Administered in Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56830/4940)
- X Chapter 4 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83820/4940) to [how much wood, dung, hyssop, and red string can be added to the red heifer fire?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83812/4940)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why not dump the ashes of the para aduma into a huge body of water?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38197/4940)
- X Chapter 6 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Parah Adumah water: different names used in the Torah ("mei niddah") and Chazal ("mei chatas")](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105599/4940)
- X Chapter 7 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Until when were the red heifer ashes still in use?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108453/4940)
- X Chapter 8 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [pouring mey chatat on a tattoo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83985/)
- X Chapter 9 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [In what situations can mei ḥatat be nullified?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108493/4940)
- X Chapter 10 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:  WAF
  [Is regular tahara implied by "b'makom tahor"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110646/3)
- X Chapter 11 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Does language change affect what hyssop is valid for the ḥatat ritual?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108494/4940)
- X Chapter 12 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [The amount of Parah Adumah ashes and water ("mei chatas") required to purify a person](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105467/4940)

Answer (score 1):

### Yadayim ידים -- DONE!

[maseches-yadayim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-yadayim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64023) to [Can one hand wash the other?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64021/)
  [Does halakha count primates as "almost human"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33824/)
- X Chapter 2 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why doesn't "first waters" in hand washing make the hand tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/)
- X Chapter 3 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Meaning of the phrase "all Holy Scripture defile the hands."](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67915/)
  [Help me find a source for glossing "sefer" (in Shabbat 14a) as "Torah, Nevi'im, and Ketuvim"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55361/)
- X Chapter 4 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13918) to [If someone had a family tradition that he came from an Edomite, would he be allowed to marry a Jew?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/)

Answer (score 0):

### Peah פאה

[masechet-peah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-peah)

*This tractate deals primarily with leaving crops for the poor.*

- O Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Peah on a circular field](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38519/5459)
  [Which plants are not subject to peah, leket, and shichecha?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96435/5459)
- O Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 4 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [A worker who did Shich'cha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12846/5459)
- O Chapter 6 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 7 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [visual aid for olelet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87360/5459)
- O Chapter 8 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:

Answer (score 0):

### Kilayim כלאים

[maseches-kilayim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kilayim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- O Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 2 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Why can't you cut down a wheat stalk before planting the other species?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82701/)
- O Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Why does R' Yishmael require the fields to alternate in Kilayim 3:6?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84087/)
- O Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Why does the Mishnah in Kilayim repeat halachos taught elsewhere?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84089/)
- O Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 6 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 7 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 8 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Why is a dog considered a wild animal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84975/)
- O Chapter 9 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Why would it be okay to wear Shaatnez to avoid being robbed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84976/)
  [Why should a Sefer Torah be obligated in Shaatnez?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84980/)

Answer (score 0):

### Sheviit שביעית

[maseches-sheviis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-sheviis)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- O Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 4 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:   
  [Why are the times for Shemitah listed in Sheviis 4:7-9?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85158/759)
- O Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:    
  [Why may one not make a business out of hunting wild animals?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85164/759)
- O Chapter 8 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:   
  [Why does R’ Akiva not just tell his students why he doesn’t hold like R’ Eliezer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/85166/759)
- O Chapter 9 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 10 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:

Answer (score 0):

### Maaserot מעשרות: DONE!

[masechet-maasrot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-maasrot)

This tractate deals with the laws of tithing produce.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27aserot)
[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.1.1)

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [If a plant / herb (grown in Eretz Yisrael) is used for its essence / aroma, must one first separate Terumah and Maaser (tithes) from it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93290/1569)
  [What does an olive press look like?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52619/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Why take t'ruma? Aren't people trusted to do so?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/76981/why-take-truma-arent-people-trusted-to-do-so)
- X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Is a courtyard for ma'aser also obligated in mezuza?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108931/1569)
- X Chapter 4 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Is there a practical difference between different ways of food becoming obligated in ma'aser?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105028/1569)
- X Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Why are there three different lists of ownerless produce?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104601/1569)

Answer (score 0):

### Maaser Sheni מעשר שני : DONE!

[tractate-maaser-sheini](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-maaser-sheini)

*tithes, percentages of new crops, animal births, and income, given to paupers or to levites or consumed in Jerusalem.*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Why can't you buy water for ma'aser sheni?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108964/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Contradiction in the Bartenura regarding value to food added by firewood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36299/1569)
  [Redeeming maaser sheini on paper money](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37516/1569)
- X Chapter 3 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: DoubleAA
  [How can Biur Sheviit precede Biur Maaser?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104719/how-can-biur-sheviit-precede-biur-maaser)
  [Maaser sheni tracking system](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93293/1569)
- X Chapter 4 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Maaser Sheni Coin Value](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84665/1569)
- X Chapter 5 (15 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [The Abolition of Vidui Ma'aser](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33770/)

Answer (score 0):

### Orlah ערלה

[tag:]

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- O Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: WAF
  [Can I make a bracha on smelling roses that may be orla?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101701/)
  [Can one smell orla tree blossoms?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101740/)
- O Chapter 2 (17 mishnayot) Claimed by: WAF
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: WAF 

  ["Saving up" an explanation on Orlah 3 (Tosafos Yom Tov)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110695/3)

Answer (score 0):

### Bikkurim בכורים: DONE!

[maseches-bikkurim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-bikkurim)

Laws regarding the first fruits.

[Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bikkurim.1)
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bikkurim_(tractate))

- X Chapter 1 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a   
  [Why do we need a derasha for thieves and muggers by Bikkurim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87140/759)
  [Why can a convert say mikra bikkurim but not viduy maaser?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108379/1569)
  [Can a convert to Judaism have a Jewish mother?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30512/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a   
  [Bikkurim 2:2 vs. Maaser Sheini 5:10](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/87213/759)
  [Is there a prohibition to eat produce before bikkurim (first fruits) have been separated?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45360/1569)
- X Chapter 3 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: b a
  [Bikkurim Baskets](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9985/1569)
  [How much produce becomes bikkurim (first fruits)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45359/1569)
  [What kind of flute was used in the temple, according to the mishna?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98267/1569)

Answer (score 0):

### Shabbat שבת: DONE!

[maseches-shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-shabbos)

The laws relating to Shabbat (the weekly day of rest), and the melakhot, or activities prohibited on Shabbat (the 39 prohibitions).

- X Chapter 1 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex

  [Explanation of Mishna in Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/60819/759)

  [Delousing on Shabbat (- Mishna, Shabbat 1:3)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17460/759)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [What do you have to check before Shabbat enters?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65193/11501)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Can one remove and return an oatmeal pot at a hotel free breakfast on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59574/can-one-remove-and-return-an-oatmeal-pot-at-a-hotel-free-breakfast-on-shabbat)

  [Is there any permissible way to put cooked dry food into an oven on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91551/is-there-any-permissible-way-to-put-cooked-dry-food-into-an-oven-on-shabbat)
- X Chapter 4 (2 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [How does salt "add heat" (mishna in Shabbos 4(1))](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9519/759)
- X Chapter 5 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Are there any practical solutions to allow carrying dog bags on Shabbas?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68253/are-there-any-practical-solutions-to-allow-carrying-dog-bags-on-shabbas)
- X Chapter 6 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Tachshitim on Shabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22585/tachshitim-on-shabbath)

  [May a woman wear a jeweled key pin on Shabbat in an area that has no eruv?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77237/may-a-woman-wear-a-jeweled-key-pin-on-shabbat-in-an-area-that-has-no-eruv)

  [Wearing a gold watch on shabbos without an eiruv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/wearing-a-gold-watch-on-shabbos-without-an-eiruv)
- X Chapter 7 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  ["Carrying" items without an eruv](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22091/carrying-items-without-an-eruv)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why is having dust on your skin not considered carrying on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/84191/11501)
- X Chapter 9 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [What is the shiur for anointing on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/20348/what-is-the-shiur-for-anointing-on-yom-kippur)

  [What modern-day hygiene products are prohibited on Yom Kippur?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30958/what-modern-day-hygiene-products-are-prohibited-on-yom-kippur)
- X Chapter 10 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50524/how-to-carry-something-with-a-shinuyœ](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50524/how-to-carry-something-with-a-shinuy%C5%93)

  [Cuttting hair and nails on shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/39090/cuttting-hair-and-nails-on-shabbos)
- X Chapter 11 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [How does deep snow affect carrying on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26148/how-does-deep-snow-affect-carrying-on-shabbos)
- X Chapter 12 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Shouldn't each of the 38 melachos ALSO be considered "מכה בפטיש"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101024/shouldnt-each-of-the-38-melachos-also-be-considered-%d7%9e%d7%9b%d7%94-%d7%91%d7%a4%d7%98%d7%99%d7%a9)

  [Why does writing on Shabbos need two letters?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10059/why-does-writing-on-shabbos-need-two-letters)
- X Chapter 13 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Is it Mutar to trap humans on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88169/is-it-mutar-to-trap-humans-on-shabbos)

  [Can I free a trapped wild animal on shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17710/can-i-free-a-trapped-wild-animal-on-shabbat)
- X Chapter 14 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Why is making salt water prohibited on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101673/11532)
- X Chapter 15 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Tying double knot of garbarge bag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/107146/tying-double-knot-of-garbarge-bag)
- X Chapter 16 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [If my home is on fire on Shabbos or Yom Tov, what can I do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25924/if-my-home-is-on-fire-on-shabbos-or-yom-tov-what-can-i-do)
- X Chapter 17 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [to grate cheese with a saw not Toveled?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75689/to-grate-cheese-with-a-saw-not-toveled)
- X Chapter 18 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Can one carry a child outside an eruv on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47957/can-one-carry-a-child-outside-an-eruv-on-shabbat)
- X Chapter 19 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [pushed off bris on shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82834/pushed-off-bris-on-shabbos)
- X Chapter 20 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Drinking Nespresso coffee on Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98650/11501)
- X Chapter 21 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Can one move egg shells on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64197/can-one-move-egg-shells-on-shabbos)
- X Chapter 22 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Squeezing Fruits on Shabbos for Juice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53031/squeezing-fruits-on-shabbos-for-juice)

  [squeezing lemon juice onto slush on shabbas](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22330/squeezing-lemon-juice-onto-slush-on-shabbas)
- X Chapter 23 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  ["Nisht Um Shabbos Geredt"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56221/nisht-um-shabbos-geredt)
- X Chapter 24 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Tying a Bow-Tie on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/62005/tying-a-bow-tie-on-shabbos)

Answer (score 0):

### Eruvin עירובין

[maseches-eruvin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-eruvin)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Eruv around towns for the purpose of carrying](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16786/eruv-around-towns-for-the-purpose-of-carrying)
  [Moving things around "opposite the gap" in an enclosure on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96917/moving-things-around-opposite-the-gap-in-an-enclosure-on-shabbat)
- O Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why can you pick your eruv if one is his Rebbe Muvhak, according to R’ Yehuda?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88334/why-can-you-pick-your-eruv-if-one-is-his-rebbe-muvhak-according-to-r-yehuda)
  [What happens when you have conflicting conditions?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88336/what-happens-when-you-have-conflicting-conditions)
- X Chapter 4 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [What tool did Raban Gamliel use to determine how close his ship was to the port?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127710/what-tool-did-raban-gamliel-use-to-determine-how-close-his-ship-was-to-the-port)
  [Orally designating a Shabas place without a landmark](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84542/orally-designating-a-shabas-place-without-a-landmark)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [וקמת ועלית - how did they measure Jerusalem's highest point?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94631/%d7%95%d7%a7%d7%9e%d7%aa-%d7%95%d7%a2%d7%9c%d7%99%d7%aa-how-did-they-measure-jerusalems-highest-point/)
- O Chapter 6 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 7 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 8 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why make an eruv with just a single-owner courtyard? (Eruvin 85)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118285/why-make-an-eruv-with-just-a-single-owner-courtyard-eruvin-85)
  [Can a woman make an eiruv for her minor children?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29115/can-a-woman-make-an-eiruv-for-her-minor-children)
- O Chapter 9 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 10 (15 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why should a הערמה be allowed and what are the guidelines for its use?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96326/why-should-a-%d7%94%d7%a2%d7%a8%d7%9e%d7%94-be-allowed-and-what-are-the-guidelines-for-its-use)

Answer (score 0):

### Shekalim שקלים

[tractate-shekalim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tractate-shekalim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani 
  [Lent half a shekel to a kohen, or gave as a present?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110480/lent-half-a-shekel-to-a-kohen-or-gave-as-a-present)
- O Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Lo Ani
- O Chapter 3 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
  [Are there "don't read X but Y" that differentiate between Tzere and Segol or Patach and Kamatz?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103890/11532)
- X Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: WAF

  [Found animals in Y'rushalayim going straight to the Mikdash without waiting for the owner?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101861/3)
- O Chapter 8 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:

Answer (score 0):

### Moed Kattan מועד קטן: DONE!

[masechet-moed-katan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-moed-katan)

Moed Kattan covers the laws of Hol Hamoed (the intermediate days of Sukkot and Passover).

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Alex

  [Watering flowers or vegetable on Chol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/102118/11501)

  [Laws of Chol Ha Moed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57137/11501)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [mbloch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Davar Ha'avad on Chol HaMoed -- Loss coming later](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26776/davar-haavad-on-chol-hamoed-loss-coming-later)

  [Can a person move during Chol HaMoed Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71506/can-a-person-move-during-chol-hamoed-pesach)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: [popularisntright](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch)

  [Who can we write a will for on Hol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104464/who-can-we-write-a-will-for-on-hol-hamoed)

Answer (score 0):

### Ketubot כתובות

[maseches-kesubos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-kesubos)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Why isn't a divorced woman mentioned in the first mishna of Maseches Kesuvos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/99913/759)
- O Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:   DanF
  [The testimony of former minors - a question on Ketubot 28a](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/86125)
- X Chapter 3 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [How a father is allowed to cause embarrassment to his underage daughter?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93766/how-a-father-is-allowed-to-cause-embarrassment-to-his-underage-daughter)
- X Chapter 4 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [Why does a Na'arah Me'orasah convert who has illicit relations not receive Skilah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101427/)
  [How can a convert be a Na'arah Me'orasah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101437/9682)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:  [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Why in the olden days was there such a long break between Kiddushin & Nisuin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99436/)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Understanding the split payments for embarrassment in Kesubos 6:1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106402/11532)
- X Chapter 7 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106697/11532) to [Why דָּת in Esther but דַּת in kidushin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56363/11532)
  [hair-covering](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hair-covering)
- X Chapter 8 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  [Heshy](/u/11532)
  [What belongs to a married woman and what can she do with it](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/63782/11532)
- X Chapter 9 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by:  [Heshy](/u/11532)
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86779/11532
- X Chapter 10 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
   [What happens when a man has multiple wives and an estate to divide amongst their kesuvos, but his estate is more than the highest of their claims?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94858/)
- X Chapter 11 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   ["Where's the court's power to assess?" Who cares?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104411/170)
- X Chapter 12 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Do Tosafos and Rambam completely agree regarding "the blessing of the house"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104413/170)
- X Chapter 13 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Is it Halachically forbidden to go to Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68493/170)

Comment: @DanF are you still planning to learn chapter 2?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Oy. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @DanF Another reminder for chapter 2 - last Perek and all of Nashim will be complete.

Comment: @DanF...? Another reminder.

Answer (score 0):

### Bava Kamma בבא קמא: DONE!

[bava-kamma](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-kamma)

Civil matters such as damages, torts and the compensation owed for them.

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Why is BK 1:2 in first person?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/107223/170)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why honor someone who teaches one thing? Say dayo lihyos k'Achisofel!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/20197/170)
- X Chapter 3 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Internal contradiction in Mishna Bava Kama 3:11?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53513/759)
- X Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Singing Mashiv Haruach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89186)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Shark ate someone](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98972/)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210

  [Which Talmudic source for Ḥanukah is the real source?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12275/which-talmudic-source-for-%e1%b8%a4anukah-is-the-real-source)
- X Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Can Jews raise pets (cats, dogs, swine)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/can-jews-raise-pets-cats-dogs-swine)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Range of Five Payments](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77138/)
- X Chapter 9 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210

  [Does one have to return the specific bills that one stole?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16797/does-one-have-to-return-the-specific-bills-that-one-stole)
  [Black? I ordered it dyed red!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108734/170)
- X Chapter 10 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210

  ["Karka Einah Nigzeles" (land can't be stolen) - really?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78712/karka-einah-nigzeles-land-cant-be-stolen-really)

Answer (score 0):

### Bava Metzia בבא מציעא: DONE!

[bava-metzia](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-metzia)

The second of the three "bavos", containing many of the laws of hoshen mishpat (Jewish civil law) including the laws of returning lost property (hashavas aveidah), custodianship (shemirah), kinyanim, fraud and overcharging (onaah and mekah taus), usury (ribis), and employment.

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  [msh210](/u/170)
  [How do I understand Bava Metzia 1:6?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45674/)
- X Chapter 2 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is the wording of these cases in the Mishna arbitrarily split?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26953/)
- X Chapter 3 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [What is the Halachah if someone lost an object despite efforts to protect it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16535/170)
- X Chapter 4 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [Why is this Mishnah repeated regarding backing out of sales?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81984)
- X Chapter 5 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: Yitzhak
  [Can donating to a Gemach be ribbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12325/can-donating-to-a-gemach-be-ribbis)
  [Are late or overdue fees Ribbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9884/are-late-or-overdue-fees-ribbis)
  [Does Ribbis apply to services?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96521/does-ribbis-apply-to-services)
  [Ribbis and Ona'ah in Monopoly](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81688/ribbis-and-onaah-in-monopoly)
  [Ribbis exception for non-observant Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59601/ribbis-exception-for-non-observant-jew)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98905/170
- X Chapter 7 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why can't a minor's rights to eat while harvesting crops be waived?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11562/1569)
- X Chapter 8 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30765/170
- X Chapter 9 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Why "for 700 zuz"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109940/170)
- X Chapter 10 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
   [Liability for damage caused by a fallen wall or fence](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78383/170)

Answer (score 0):

### Bava Batra בבא בתרא: DONE!

[bava-batra](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bava-batra)

A tractate focused on a person's responsibilities and rights as the owner of property

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Rosh's view on a yard near a roof: do both pay for 10 tefach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10451/170)
- X Chapter 2 (14 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Is mustard harmful to bees or the honey making process?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104505/)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70160/170
- X Chapter 4 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [When selling a house, what pieces of furniture go with it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108752/when-selling-a-house-what-pieces-of-furniture-go-with-it)
- X Chapter 5 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Does a seller acquire each coin one at a time, or all at once?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53025/does-a-seller-acquire-each-coin-one-at-a-time-or-all-at-once)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Underground crypts for burial](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48926/underground-crypts-for-burial)
- X Chapter 7 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Questions about the fence dividing a subdivided field](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57405/170)
- X Chapter 8 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Father as an heir](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105763/father-as-an-heir)
- X Chapter 9 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: mbloch

  [Who inherits if a man and wife die together?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83705/)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210

  [Why do many boys begin learning Gemara with Elu Metzios?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53778/170)

Answer (score 0):

### Shevuot שבועות: DONE!

[masechet-shevuot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-shevuot)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Why does the atonement for impurity in the Temple take so many different forms?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70918/170)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [What is the halachic boundary of modern day Jerusalem in regards to Purim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111438/170)
  [Nidda after wedding](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18289/170)
- X Chapter 3 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [What if one swears to do something forbidden?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82864)
- X Chapter 4 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Can one be compelled to testify?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89622/170)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [What is the penalty for raping (or seducing) an unmarried non virgin girl in "Halaca"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105972/170)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [What are the 3 shvuot that are d'oraisa?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98050/170)
- X Chapter 7 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61115/170
- X Chapter 8 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/49280/

Comment: @Leopold any update?

Answer (score 0):

### Eduyot עדיות: DONE!

[eduyot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eduyot)

*A series of miscellaneous mishnayot created by testimony given by the rabbis*

- X Chapter 1 (14 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [How can Bet Shamai argue on Shamai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96336/)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [Why were the Egyptians judged for twelve lunar months, rather than solar ones?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101597/)
  [Moshe's age and the timeline of the exodus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8438/170)
- X Chapter 3 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How does tumah work in the sale of an oven between a householder and a baker?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103842/170)
- X Chapter 4 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why isn't Keilim 20:6 reckoned amongst the stringencies of Beit Hillel and the leniencies of Beit Shammai?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105566/170)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How were the Rabbis allowed to trick Karkamit?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88585/)
- X Chapter 6 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91318/170
- X Chapter 7 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36086/170
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Tumah of liquids: a question on Bartenura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105099/tumah-of-liquids-a-question-on-bartenura)

  [How come we don't bring the Pesach offering in Israel now?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81392/how-come-we-dont-bring-the-pesach-offering-in-israel-now)

Answer (score 0):

### Zevachim זבחים - DONE!

[maseches-zevachim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-zevachim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Number of sages in the Sanhedrin of Yavneh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/number-of-sages-in-the-sanhedrin-of-yavneh)
- X Chapter 2 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [How does Lev. 6:3 demonstrate that a kohen's tunic must rest directly on his skin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/104714/how-does-lev-63-demonstrate-that-a-kohens-tunic-must-rest-directly-on-his-ski)
- X Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Was it always the kohen who slaughtered the korbanot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27157/was-it-always-the-kohen-who-slaughtered-the-korbanot)
  [During Temple times, who can butcher a kosher animal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101733/during-temple-times-who-can-butcher-a-kosher-animal)
- X Chapter 4 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Sotah saving herself by disqualifying the mincha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104920/2)
- X Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Location of the Beit HaDeshen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9061/)
- X Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why is melika - not shechita - done on the bird korban?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81412/2)
  [Dimensions of the Copper/Outer/Olah Mizbeach in the Mishkan](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56681/2)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Can meat ever be both "treifa" AND "neveila"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5428/2)
- X Chapter 8 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Practicalities of the "graze until they become defected" strategy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105914/practicalities-of-the-graze-until-they-become-defected-strategy)
- X Chapter 9 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [How does one get an animal off of the Altar surreptitiously?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106063/2)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [How is Tadir determined when either one can be considered more common?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94443/how-is-tadir-determined-when-either-one-can-be-considered-more-common)
  [Why do we don a tallit before laying tefillin?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81409/why-do-we-don-a-tallit-before-laying-tefillin)
- X Chapter 11 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Why may the me'il, in particular, not be torn?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55763/why-may-the-meil-in-particular-not-be-torn)
- X Chapter 12 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Did Rabbi Akiva accept arguments from ignorance?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105386/did-rabbi-akiva-accept-arguments-from-ignorance)
- X Chapter 13 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Sukkot water libations - from the Torah, from Sinai, or from the Rabbis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108870/sukkot-water-libations-from-the-torah-from-sinai-or-from-the-rabbis)
- X Chapter 14 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [Heter Bamos - When?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108730/heter-bamos-when)

Answer (score 0):

### Bechorot בכורות : DONE!

[maseches-bechoros](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-bechoros)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: @SamuelManuel
  [Why don't some do yibum today, l'chatchilah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41126/1569)
  [Can one lechatchila choose to behead a firstborn donkey?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97036/1569)
- X Chapter 2 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: @SamuelManuel
  [Would a genetically engineered red heifer be usable?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27690/1569)
- X Chapter 3 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: @SamuelManuel
  [What's the significance of putting a firstborn animal's hair in the window?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110067/1569)
- X Chapter 4 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: @SamuelManuel
  [Rabbi's liability for giving a wrong psak](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104362/1569)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: @SamuelManuel
  [Practicalities of the "graze until they become defected" strategy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105914/1569)
- X Chapter 6 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Ear Piercing of Jewish slave that wants to stay a slave a mum?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70397/1569)
  [Getting body piercings](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29293/1569)
- X Chapter 7 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Birkat Kohanim for a Kohen who was very far from Judaism and decided to be a good Jew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73780/1569)
  [Kohanim unfit to serve](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81601/1569)
- X Chapter 8 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Performing a C-section in the Time of Chazal](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62221/1569)
  [Does a child born to a mother that converted when she was pregnant need Pidyon HaBen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/68770/1569)
  [Why no early pidyon haben?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117649/170)
- X Chapter 9 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Are there still those who obey the mitzvah of Ma'aser Behemah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45326/1569)

Comment: @Samuel claim one chapter at a time please

Comment: @Samuel the X mark is for chapters that have been studied and have a linked question. Please reread the question post for details about how to participate.

Answer (score 0):

### Erchin ערכין : DONE!

[arachin-tractate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arachin-tractate)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by:  Mithical
  [A shoteh doesn't vow to donate — isn't this obvious?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109008/a-shoteh-doesnt-vow-to-donate-isnt-this-obvious)
  [How is a "Goses" (someone who is about to die) defined?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/110520/how-is-a-goses-someone-who-is-about-to-die-defined)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [How does Rambam understand Arachin 8a?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105200/how-does-rambam-understand-arachin-8a/105212#105212)
- X Chapter 3 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Understanding Avot DeRabbi Natan 9:2 about Lashon Hara](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73340/170)
- X Chapter 4 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Singing the Mishna: sources](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69727/170)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Were there particular reasons to vow the value of a person?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/83135/170)
- X Chapter 6 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Wealth-based sacrifices: how to determine wealth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37354/170)
  [What is it with Chazal and garlic?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100579/170) (PTIJ)
- X Chapter 7 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Redeeming s'dei achuzah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/114269/170)
- X Chapter 8 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [In auctions today are you still obligated after being out-bid?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14100/)
- X Chapter 9 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How did the Sages know that Jerusalem had a wall in the times of Joshua?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4679/170)

Answer (score 0):

### Temurah תמורה : DONE!

[maseches-temura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-temura)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: [Mithical](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/7420/mithical)
  [Why is there a difference between someone inheriting an animal and a Kohen receiving it from a Yisrael for the purposes of T'murah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110450/7420)
- X Chapter 2 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: Mithical
  [Why are public sacrifices always male but personal ones are not?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/110599/7420)
- X Chapter 3 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Is there a special status for the offspring of an animal that was dedicated for a Karban?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31642/170)
- X Chapter 4 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why must Chata'os Ha-meisos be treated so harshly?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70/170)
- X Chapter 5 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Did Yiftach's daughter have to comply with his vow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/106610/170)
- X Chapter 6 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Dog that was exchanged for a lamb](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108317)
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is a difference between קדשי מזבח and קדשי בדק הבית listed among their similarities?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117831/170)

Answer (score 0):

### Keritot כריתות

[masechet-kereitot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-kereitot)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
  [What is "piggul"? A question on the Bartenura](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61565/what-is-piggul-a-question-on-the-bartenura?rq=1)
- O Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: Isaac Moses
- X Chapter 3 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [The Rambam's Nekudah Neflah (נקודה נפלאה)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10023/170)
- X Chapter 4 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Explanation of מיגו דהאי לאו דאיסורא הוא דהאי נמי לאו איסורא הוא](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83059/170)
- X Chapter 5 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Prohibition to eat blood](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/100103/170)
- X Chapter 6 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why do we think of the korban pesach as a sheep, not as a goat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14351/170)

Comment: Isaac, any update on chapter 2?

Comment: @msh210 I learned it. I actually learned it many months ago, I confirmed on Shemini Atzeret. I just have to find or write a relevant post.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88578/170 is weakly related.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/117834/170 is strongly related but is an answer (and a weak one at that)

Comment: @msh210 What I mean to do is ask a ta'amei hamitzvot question about the laws of Shifcha Charufa. I just need one of [these](https://www.flickr.com/photos/denisemattox/3382089636).

Answer (score 0):

### Meilah מעילה : DONE!

[maseches-meila](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-meila)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: [msh210](/u/170)
  [Yitzchak Avinu and Eretz Yisrael](//judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48489/170)
- X Chapter 2 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is there m'ila until the ashes are removed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118010/170)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [How did the priests deal with excess blood during the Temple dedication?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/41022/170)
- X Chapter 4 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:  msh210
  [What is the shiur Hanaah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50370/170)
- X Chapter 5 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Etymology of קטלא (necklace, in משניות מעילה)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118028/170)
- X Chapter 6 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Can Etrog and Lulav be too cheap?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108969/170)
  [What happened to the rest of masechet Meilah -- it ends at 22a but the daf yomi calendar says it goes to 37?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16240/170)

Answer (score 0):

### Middot מדות: DONE!

[masechet-midot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masechet-midot)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [Why would they beat up Leviim who fell asleep on the job and burn their clothes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/106938/)
  [Is there any connection between the Sotah, the Mizbeiach, and the Beis HaMikdash keychain?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106998/)
  [Orientation of Kahati's map of the Beis Hamikdash](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108849/orientation-of-kahatis-map-of-the-beis-hamikdash)
- X Chapter 2 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [Why does the Mishnah record the significance of the fifteen steps but not the twelve steps?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106939/)
  [What are "rashei pispasin"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88437/)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [Is there any connection between the Sotah, the Mizbeiach, and the Beis HaMikdash keychain?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106998/)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [Difference between תא and לשכה](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108773/)
- X Chapter 5 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: DonielF
  [How big was the Lishkas HaGazis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95767/)

Comment: I can retroactively use my question on the fifth perek for my question for this, right?

Comment: @DonielF Sure! You can use any post on Mi Yodeya that's related to your chapter.

Answer (score 0):

### Ohalot אוהלות

[maseches-oholos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-oholos)

- X Chapter 1 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72 
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83442/
  [Is there a list of the 365 sinews?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83440/)
- X Chapter 2 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/82025/4940) to [how much is required to make something tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82024/how-much-is-required-to-make-something-tamei/82025#82025)
- X Chapter 3 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Can a natural hollow become an Ohel for Tum'ah through human use?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/109247/4940)
- X Chapter 4 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How can tumah pass through a cupboard?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/122225/how-can-tumah-pass-through-a-cupboard)
- X Chapter 5 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/49138
- O Chapter 6 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 7 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50334/4940) to [Medical treatment for pregnant woman that jeopardises pregnancy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50333/4940)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88379/4940) to [Can a kohen be born tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88375/can-a-kohen-be-born-tamei/88379#88379)
- X Chapter 8 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Hebrew for ice - and other "new" words](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7829)
- X Chapter 9 (16 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [How does a c'zayit of a body practically get inside the hive when it fills the house (Ohalot 9:9)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/57507/759)
- O Chapter 10 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 11 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71486/170
- X Chapter 12 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Why measure the side of the square by quartering its circumference](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/103965/501)
  [Identity of "the Greek rabbi" in the Raavad's gloss (Tum'at Met 17:3)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67388/4940)
- O Chapter 13 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 14 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 15 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [How can a solid pile of planks be considered an ohel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117727/4940)
- X Chapter 16 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68161/4940) to [How do you inspect a field for graves?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64749/4940)
- X Chapter 17 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3263
- X Chapter 18 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How is a kohen allowed to go outside Israel?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15273)

Comment: I've learned the as-yet unclaimed _p'rakim_, too, but can't find or think of posts for them.

Answer (score 0):

### Taharot טהרות : DONE!

[maseches-taharos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-taharos)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38218
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [What is the Tuma status of food which touched a corpse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31904)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65569
- X Chapter 4 (13 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [What is a Safek Muchlat? (i.e. unsure if he's a full-fledged Metzora)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93341)
- X Chapter 5 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why is one who touched doubtful Tumah in a public domain considered Tahor?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80727)
- X Chapter 6 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [How many types of reshut exist?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65192)
- X Chapter 7 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14713
- X Chapter 8 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Understanding the case in the start of טהרות ח:ח](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/127552)
- X Chapter 9 (9 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Do cremated remains contaminate with tumas mes?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27806)
- X Chapter 10 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Is a wooden knife מקבל טומאה?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47492)

Comment: Yasher Koach, @msh210!

Comment: Baruch tihye, @IsaacMoses!

Answer (score 0):

### Machshirin מכשירין: DONE!

[maseches-machshirin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-machshirin)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Machshirin 1:6: Chazon Ish's defence's of Bartenura's peirush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117112/4940)
- X Chapter 2 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/84833/4940) to [Can a non Jew bake bread on Pesach for a Jew to use after Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14266/4940)
- X Chapter 3 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why argue over whether people want their wheat wet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/127950)
- X Chapter 4 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Retrieving fallen produce while washing your hands in a stream](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108938/4940)
- X Chapter 5 (11 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48085/4940) to [Can I make a mikvah using artificial rain?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26921/4940)
- X Chapter 6 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Licking fingers for Mayim Acharonim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48697/4940)
  [Dew distinct from water among the shiva mashkim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1294/4940)
  [Does soda machshir for receiving tuma?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/99163/does-soda-machshir-for-receiving-tuma)

Answer (score 0):

### Zavim זבים : DONE!

[maseches-zavim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-zavim)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why does the second day ruin the count, and the third day not?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128038)
- X Chapter 2 (4 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/108591
- X Chapter 3 (3 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  [Why are אוכלי חולין בטהרה called "בני הכנסת"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128058)
- X Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [consequences of minor tumah nowadays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/95987/4940)
- X Chapter 5 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: msh210
  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/60980

Answer (score 0):

### Tevul Yom טבול יום

[tag:]

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- O Chapter 1 (5 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- X Chapter 2 (8 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78361/4940) to [Where does Rashi say that less than a kezayis of oil does not become impure?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78350/4940)
- O Chapter 3 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by:
- O Chapter 4 (7 mishnayot) Claimed by:

Answer (score 0):

### Uktzim עוקצים: DONE!

[maseches-uktzin](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maseches-uktzin)

*Add synopsis and resource links here*

- X Chapter 1 (6 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Can handles become tamei?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/108909/4940)
- X Chapter 2 (10 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Stringing nuts together: a question on the Bartenura, Uqtzin 2:5](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71129/759)
- X Chapter 3 (12 mishnayot) Claimed by: magicker72
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/67356/4940) to [R' Yehoshua Ben Levi -- A Tanna or an Amorah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29244/4940)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16921/4940) to [Why is there so much space and matter,etc. in the universe?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16914/4940)
  [Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73969/4940) to [What is the earliest source that mentions Gematria?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6359/4940)