# Siyum Project - Progress and How to Help

Tags: discussion, group-siyum

**Progess on the [Siyum Project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mis)**

I'll try to update this every Sunday, reflecting updates through the most recent Sunday morning [Stack Exchange data dump](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq). The goal is to complete all 523 chapters before the celebration, which will be at some point in December.

[image: Chart showing how many chapters have been completed so far]

**Here's what you can do to help get us across the finish line:**

1. [Learn Mishna](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-tenth-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mis)! Each chapter learned is a great contribution!
   Would you consider challenging yourself to learn two mishnayot per day? Nine people doing that for the duration of the project would carry the whole thing.
2. Find MY posts that address a particular chapter of Mishna or Talmud and add their links to the appropriate places in the project's index, even if you're not currently learning that chapter. That'll make it easier for whoever does.
3. Promote this project to people who may take part. For example, retweet [this tweet](https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya/status/1111011696183775234) or copy its content or gist to your favorite social network.
4. Edit in tag links and synopses for the tractates, to help others decide what to learn and find posts.

Comment: Suggestion: could you quantify how much chapters are required a week every week until end December to finish time? And publish this in chat? I think it might help make the issue smaller and therefore more achievable. Would indeed be nice to finish in time !