# Should PTIJ and/or other closed questions go into the group siyum?

Tags: discussion, group-siyum

From comments on the [main group siyum post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/11532):

- Should PTIJ be excluded?
- Should other closed questions be excluded?

Within the "exclude" side, there are two options:

1. They don't count towards the goal of having a question per perek, but should still be posted in addition to a real question
2. Leave them out entirely

Answer (score 5):

I think closed, non-PTIJ questions should be left out entirely.  They're closed because they're a bad fit for the site, so adding them to the siyum post is just unnecessary noise.

PTIJ questions should definitely not count towards the goal of having a question per perek.  They can be added at the bottom of the masechet's post, in a labeled spoiler section.

If a question that is closed as a duplicate contains some extra information related to a mishnah, but the main question doesn't (as pointed out by DoubleAA), my proposal is as follows:

- If the information improves the question, it should be edited into the main question.
- If it's extraneous, then it probably would have been edited out of the duplicate if it hadn't been closed as a duplicate, so it shouldn't count.
- There could be some corner cases not covered by either of those two possibilites, where it actually makes sense to refer to a duplicate (e.g. why don't Jews consider Bar Kochva Mashiach, answer refers to נלכדה בתר, then it was marked as a duplicate of the main reference question), but they should be very rare and I would take those on a case by case basis.

Comment: What about duplicates? A duplicate might mention a Mishna that the open version doesn't mention

Comment: "refers to a mishnah": note that [the _siyum_](/q/5029) doesn't require that the post refer to the chapter, only that it "relate[] directly to" the chapter. For example, if you see a question that quotes the verbatim codification of a _mishna_ in _halacha_ and doesn't refer to the _mishna_ at all, that'd (IMO) definitely count toward the ["Mi Yodeya twist"](/q/5029) requirement.

Comment: @msh210 how about this?

Comment: (re your comment addressed to me) Looks good, thanks.

Comment: I disagree with the notion that every reference in a duplicate either should be in the original or should/would be edited out. The whole point of keeping dupes around is that they come at the same question in a different way, which is valuable. Unlike answers, questions are not supposed to strive for some ideal of comprehesiveness.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I guess what you're saying is that most cases will fit into my third bullet?  I can accept that.