# Pinging without a dot

Tags: support, comments, username

I am usually pinged with my full username [Dr. Shmuel]. However, sometimes people will remove the dot.

I have it on record that *[rov](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/604/16706)* ([1,](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106371/best-way-to-explain-to-my-boss-that-i-cannot-attend-a-team-summit-because-it-is#comment356547_106371) [2,](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-10th-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mish/5082#comment16105_5082) [3](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106504/why-doesnt-r-yehuda-believe-the-eidim-zomemim-after-the-first-set#comment357210_106504)) of the 
moderators have pinged me as [DrShmuel] without using this dot.

Some question are now begged.

In the course of normal conversation in the comments, am may be pinged even with an [@] if I was directly prior to the next comment. However, with this pinging method not including the dot [DrShmuel] I receive no pings whatsoever. Even when I would have normally been pinged (see fig. 3) through the succession system in the comments. I presume the system thinks a certain [DrShmuel] is being paged, and leaves me [Dr. Shmuel] out of it.

Is the system supposed to ignore dots? Or has this all  been a case of mistaken dots.

Comment: The easiest solution, of course, is to just remove the dot from your name.

Comment: @DanielF I see.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Great reply.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're seeing "manual" pings as opposed to auto-completed ones.

(1) is mine.  I was using my phone at the time and didn't get the "pop-up" for auto-completion that we get on the desktop site.  I thought that was just a client-side problem and would be fixed in the posted comment, but I guess not.  Typing on a phone is somewhat challenging; I apologize for that, and also for the lack of capitalization.

(2) was almost certainly typed manually; you don't have any comments there, *but* comments can ping people who've edited a post.  So there, too, your name was imperfectly typed.  (I have no special knowledge of #3.)

I conclude from this that @-pings must be exact in order to actually produce the notification, and that when we need to type them manually we have to be extra-careful.  I didn't know that omitted punctuation would block a ping, since (I know from being on the receiving end) case mismatch does not block.

Comment: I’ve manually typed DrShmuel and he was pinged, so I’m not sure if your conclusion is correct. Then again, I usually use the iOS app, which has some bugs in commenting anyway.

Comment: @DonielF Interesting.

Comment: @drshmuel test ping

Comment: @DoubleAA no show

Comment: @dr. test ping.

Comment: @DoubleAA Bingo.