# Is there a shu"t mi yodea

Tags: discussion

Has anyone made a shu"t mi yodea?
Something like organizing the questions here in order of the shulchan aruch?

Not sure if this question is on topic in any way but I had to ask.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone's tried anything like that yet, but we have some related artifacts:

- Of course, you can find Q&A by topic by browsing our tags.
- In a related concept, we started, but never finished, a catalog of chapters of Mishna with at least one Mi Yodeya Q&A listed for each, at: [To celebrate Mi Yodeya's 10th birthday, let's divide and conquer the entire Mishna, Mi-Yodeya-style!](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/to-celebrate-mi-yodeyas-10th-birthday-lets-divide-and-conquer-the-entire-mish)
- We have published a series of edited anthologies of Q&A much smaller than the one you describe, but maybe of related form, under [Mi Yodeya Publications](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications)